# Razor ViewEngine HTML.Checkbox method creates a hidden input. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, checkbox

I have written the below code on my view page;

```
@Html.CheckBox("ChxName",true)
```

and I got the following result;

```
<input checked="checked" id="ChxName" name="ChxName" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="ChxName" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

why is there a input element named as the same with checkbox?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Unchecked checkboxes are not posted, so the hidden field (set as false) allows the model binding to still work.

Look at Request.Form on the post back. If the checkbox is checked, you'll see:

```
ChxName=true&ChxName=false
```

The model binder uses the first value.

and, if the box isn't checked, you'll see:

```
ChxName=false
```

Comment: so that means, this checkbox will be passed as false to the controller?

Comment: Only if the box is not checked. If it's checked, it will be bound with true.  Give it a try with the debugger.  Also, try it without the HTML Helper and you can see why they made it that way.

Comment: so as I understood, the hidden field value turns out true if checkbox is checked and the controller gets the value of hidden field after that. am I following you here right?

Comment: No, the hidden value will _always_ be false and is _always_ posted.  If the box is checked, a true is also posted and the model binder uses the true value.  This is a common question, so you might want to google around a bit if you still don't understand or simply look at the mvc source code.

Comment: @ericvg thanks a lot for your help. I'll dig into mvc source code when I got a time.

Comment: No problem -- here is another SO answer that might explain it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input

Comment: great :) the good point is that it will work easily with AJAX

Answer (score 3):

ericvg explained it well.

The manual approach is this:

```
bool IsDefault = (Request.Form["IsDefault"] != "false");
```

Answer (score 3):

Or use Contains("true") which I find a bit neater...

```
bool myCheckBoxValue = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["MyCheckBoxValue"]).Contains("true");
```