# Get values from unchecked checkboxes (FormCollection) - MVC3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

Why are the unchecked checkboxes not in the collection?
I can only access the values from the checked ones.

I need it because i want to delete all unchecked from my DB.

Here a code sample:

```
foreach (var item in collection.AllKeys.Where(c => c.StartsWith("check_projekt_")).Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
{
                if (collection[item.Data] == "1")
                {
                    dbclass.addUserToProjekt(Convert.ToInt32(collection["projekt_" + item.Index]), Convert.ToDouble(collection["input_projekt_" + item.Index]), mID);
                }
                else {
                    dbclass.deleteUserFromProjekt(Convert.ToInt32(collection["projekt_" + item.Index]), mID);
                }
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Html.CheckBox("cbName",true)` method in Razor to create the checkbox.  MVC also adds a hidden input field for each checkbox, so you can see everything with a true/false state.  See this post for more info:

[Razor ViewEngine HTML.Checkbox method creates a hidden input. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462967/razor-viewengine-html-checkbox-method-creates-a-hidden-input-why)

Comment: Ok i tried it, but when i try to get the value from the collection, then i'm getting "true,false" as value ??

Comment: Hmmm.  You may have to bind your collection to a view model for that approach to work.  Ideally, you should be using view models anyway, rather than working with the FormCollection directly.

Comment: Yes, i know - but it worked with FormCollection now. (I checked it with "true,false" string hehe :)