# Why is the following javaScript code not returning any elements?

Tags: javascript, html

Why is the following javaScript code not returning any elements?

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="misc" data-custom-test="test1" data-custom-test="test2"></div>
```

Here is the javaScript code:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-custom-test="' + "test2" + '"]');
alert(elements.length);
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: just see finish html: your div have just first attribute

Comment: @hendry: Not sure why you're linking to that help article. Do you not see an MCVE in the question?

Answer (score 5):

When I run experiments in a jsFiddle in Chrome, `document.querySelectorAll()` will only find a match on a given element if the FIRST attribute with a given attribute name is the one that matches your selector.  Or said, another way, if you have multiple definitions of the same attribute, `document.querySelectorAll()` is not finding matches in any of them other than the first one.

I have not tested other browsers to see how they behave in this regard, but this is enough to tell you that you have a problem using multiple definitions of the same attribute name like you are.

Further, the [Section 8.1.2.3 about Attributes in the HTML5 spec here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) clearly states that you are not to have duplicate attribute in the same tag.

> There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose
>   names are an ASCII case-insensitive match for each other.

---

I don't know what problem you're really trying to solve here, but a common practice is to use multiple values on the same attribute definition by separating the multiple values with a separator like a semicolon and then you could use the `*=` operator in your selector to find attributes that contain a substring like this:

```
<div class="misc" data-custom-test="test1;test2"></div>

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-custom-test*="' + "test2" + '"]');
console.log(elements.length);
```

Comment: possibly by specification applied only first? and next just ignore?

Comment: Alternatively, using a space as the separator allows you to use `[data-custom-test~=test2]`, ensuring you don't match partial values incorrectly, but it has the caveat of reserving the space character as the separator.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that elements cannot have duplicate attributes ([see a similar question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341507/can-a-dom-element-have-the-same-attribute-twice)). From the [W3C link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) provided in Jukka K. Korpela's answer:

> There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose names are an ASCII case-insensitive match for each other.

The result may vary from browser to browser, but it seems that generally the second attribute is directly ignored. For example, the same thing happens if you have a duplicate `style` attributes:

```html
<div style="color:red;" style="color:blue;">Is it red or blue?</div>
```