# HTML ignoring internal CSS

Tags: html, css

I am beginning to make a responsive website for different screen sizes. This is the first time I have used internal css. When I run the code, the image appears, however, it seems as though the content of the style tags is being ignored. Can anyone please help?

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" content="initial-scale=1">
    <!-- This sets the website, on any device, to fit the size of the screen. -->

    <!-- Internal Style sheet -->

    <style type ="text/css">

        i {
        width: 100%;
        }

        #tl_square {
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 33.3333%;
        float: left;
        padding: 2%;
        }

        #tr_square {
        max-width: 1000px;
        width: 66.6667%;
        float: right;
        padding: 1%;
        }

        #ml_square {
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 33.3333%;
        float: left;
        padding: 2%;
        }

        #mm_square {
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        padding: 2%;
        }

        #mr_square {
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 50%;
        float: right;
        padding: 2%;
        }

        #m_nested_square {
        max-width: 1000px;
        width: 66.6667%
        float:right;
        }

        #bl_square {
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 33.3333%;
        float: left;
        max-height: 500px
        height: 33.3333%;
        padding: 2%;
        }

        #br_square {
        max-width: 1000px;
        width: 66.6667%;
        float: right;
        max-height: 500px
        height: 33.3333%;
        padding: 1%;
        }




    </style>


    <title> jamesnovis.com 
    </title>


</head>


<body>

    <!-- The top boxes -->
    <div id="tl_square"> 
        <img src="testimage.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="tr_square"> 
    </div>


    <!-- The middle boxes -->
    <div id="ml_square">
    </div>

    <!-- These are nested divs -->
    <div id="m_nested_square">
        <div id="mm_square">
        </div>

        <div id="mr_square">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- The bottom boxes -->
    <div id="bl_square">
    </div>

    <div id="br_square">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: by the way it does end with </body> </html> I don't know why it didn't show when I pasted it.

Comment: Can you post the whole html code as one block ? Btw, `<style type ="text/css">` is incorrect (extra space), `<style>` alone is enough (no need to pricse the type)

Comment: If you are applying style to img then in style tag do this : #tl_square > img

Comment: you meta viewport is incorrect: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Your `meta` tag is incorrect as point out by @fcalderan as well as there is no need of specifying `text/css` in style tag. By default <style> tag will take CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Missing few semicolons, and the wrong format of the meta viewport; here's it:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- meta viewport, the content was not rightly assigned -->
<!-- This sets the website, on any device, to fit the size of the screen. -->

<!-- Internal Style sheet -->

<style type="text/css">
    i {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #tl_square {
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 33.3333%;
        float: left;
        padding: 2%;
    }

    #tr_square {
        max-width: 1000px;
        width: 66.6667%;
        float: right;
        padding: 1%;
    }

    #ml_square {
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 33.3333%;
        float: left;
        padding: 2%;
    }

    #mm_square {
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        padding: 2%;
    }

    #mr_square {
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 50%;         /* semicolon ';' was missing */
        float: right;
        padding: 2%;
    }

    #m_nested_square {
        max-width: 1000px;
        width: 66.6667%;        /* semicolon ';' was missing */
        float: right;
    }

    #bl_square {
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 33.3333%;
        float: left;
        max-height: 500px;
        height: 33.3333%;
        padding: 2%;
    }

    #br_square {
        max-width: 1000px;
        width: 66.6667%;
        float: right;
        max-height: 500px;      /* semicolon ';' was missing */
        height: 33.3333%;
        padding: 1%;
    }
</style>


<title>jamesnovis.com</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Dom Element should not have same attribute defined twice as indicated here : [Can an HTML element have the same attribute twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341507/can-a-dom-element-have-the-same-attribute-twice)

Combining content attribute as shown in answer by @Nav042 or removing one of them should fix the issue.

Also, if you forget a semi-colon in CSS, rest of the CSS would be ignored and won't apply on target elements.