# why cant get the value of <a> tag from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know whats the problem of my JavaScript or my code.
I can't get the `data-value` of an `<a>` tag from HTML.
I don't know what's wrong because I am just a beginner in JavaScript.

I have a loop where I have many categories in my website and I put a value of id from my `<a>` tag.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <?php foreach($data as $single_data) { ?>
  <a href="#" id="target" data-value="<?php echo $single_data->Category_id; ?>" class="list-group-item"><?= $single_data->Category_name ?></a>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

When i go to show page source it looks good and look like this:

```
<a href="#" id="target" data-value="1" class="list-group-item">Gadgets</a>
<a href="#" id="target" data-value="2" class="list-group-item">Books</a>
```

Now here is my JavaScript:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).data("value");
    alert(value);
});
```

Comment: You cannot have two IDs with same name. IDs are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` need to be unique. You can use class as a selector in your problem

```js
$(".list-group-item").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).data("value");
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-value="1" class="list-group-item">Gadgets</a>
<a href="#" data-value="2" class="list-group-item">Books</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Id of the tag should be unique** 
You can do something like

```
<a href="#" id="target1" data-value="1" class="list-group-item">Gadgets</a>
<a href="#" id="target2" data-value="2" class="list-group-item">Books</a>
```

Or if you want to capture click event for both anchor tags you can use class selector instead

```js
$(".list-group-item").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).data("value");
    alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="target" data-value="1" class="list-group-item">Gadgets</a>
<a href="#" id="target" data-value="2" class="list-group-item">Books</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change two things :

- id of  elements have to be unique
- bound each  element with a click() function.

And html side :

```
<a href="#" id="targetGadget" data-value="1" class="list-group-item">Gadgets</a>
<a href="#" id="targetBook" data-value="2" class="list-group-item">Books</a>
```

JS side :

```
$("#targetGadget").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).data("value");
    alert(value);
});
$("#targetBook").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).data("value");
    alert(value);
});
```

---

Now, from JS side, to not repeat yourself, a better way would be to add `<a>` elements in a div in the html side and in the js dynamically applying the `click()` function for each of `<a>` child of the div.

Here is an example :

html :

```
div id="targets">
  <a href="#" id="targetGadget" data-value="1" class="list-group-item">Gadgets</a>
  <a href="#" id="targetBook" data-value="2" class="list-group-item">Books</a>
</div>
```

js :

```
var children = $("#targets").get(0).children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = children[i];
    $(child).click(function() {
        var value = $(this).data("value");
        alert(value);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

IDs are always unique. You CANNOT have same ID to different DOM elements. In that case, assign them a class.

Changed the ID to class, and accordingly made change in JS code:

```js
$(".target").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).data("value");
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="target list-group-item" data-value="1">Gadgets</a>
<a href="#" class="target list-group-item" data-value="2">Books</a>
```

Comment: You cannot have two `class` attributes

Comment: yea got it. i include the class in list-group-item

Comment: @freefaller - Have updated it. Yet, 2 classes isn't a problem and doesn't mean a down-vote?!

Comment: Oops. Sorry @freefaller :)

Comment: @Milan - for the record, [2 instances of the same attribute in the same element **is** a problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26341866/930393)