# Is it better to use one event binding with multiple functions or multiple event binding with one function?

Tags: angular

Should i use `<a (click)="f1(); f2()">` or `<a (click)="f1()" (click)="f2()">` ?

I don't care about the order, and I don't want to create another function to call the 2 others.

Comment: have you actually tried both solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341507/can-an-html-element-have-the-same-attribute-twice

Comment: @Kaddath: yes that work on both case

Comment: even if the second solution works (which was not the case in angularjs at least), why would you do that? It's like wanting to deliver 2 eggs and ask if it's a better solution to rent 2 cars to do it, while it fits in a single one..

Comment: I saw some code with that (latest) and was not sure if it's need to be refactored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to create another function to call the 2 others.

Probably that would be the cleanest thing to do.

Comment: I think I'll end up doing that, it's more a theorical question if i had to use only HTML.