# How to select tag in CSS with 2 classes

Tags: html, css

I want to make  bigger selector specificity

```
//HTML        
<input type="button" class="button filled" class="button icon" value="Learn More">

//CSS
.button.filled button.icon
{

}
```

Comment: `.class1, .class2 {...}`

Comment: why cant you have class="button filled icon" instead of 2 class

Comment: You can have multiple values inside a `class` attribute, but not multiple `class`es within a single `HTML` element.

Comment: I want to change only the input tag that have both tags

Comment: "both tags"?  there are 3 classes here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="button filled" class="button icon" value="Learn More">
```

You can't have multiple `class=""` attributes in an element, that's illegal in HTML:

[Can an HTML element have the same attribute twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341507/can-an-html-element-have-the-same-attribute-twice)

> When the user agent leaves the attribute name state (and before emitting the tag token, if appropriate), the complete attribute's name must be compared to the other attributes on the same token; **if there is already an attribute on the token with the exact same name, then this is a parse error and the new attribute must be dropped, along with the value that gets associated with it** (if any).

So browsers will only respect the first `class` attribute (in your case `class="button filled"` and ignore the `class="button icon"` attribute). This may explain why you're not seeing expected behaviour.

In any event, a single `class="button filled icon"` attribute and selector `.button.filled.icon` is what you want.

You might also want to use `input[type=button].icon` instead.

That said, you should avoid using `<input type="button">` and `<input type="submit">` and use `<button type="button">` and `<button type="submit">` instead because they let you specify inner content and a separate `value=""` attribute.

Comment: Some browsers (tested with Firefox, IE and chrome) seams not use the value attribute for HTML button tag text which you claimed more or less it's possible to use..  Also why would advice to avoid using the `<input />` tag it's modern valid HTML 4, 5 and valid XHTML there is nothing wrong using that.. Which are most likely the causes off the downvote see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y4jurzgw/), all HTML button tag texts are empty..

Comment: @RaymondNijland All current browsers (as of early 2019) correctly handle the `<button value="foo" type="submit">` element. Only older versions of IE (older than IE10) handle it differently and they are all obsolete.

Comment: @RaymondNijland As I said, the `<input type="button">` element does not let you use different values for the `value="" `attribute and the button's displayed text, whereas `<button>` lets you use other HTML elements (like `<img />`) as child content displayed inside the button.

Comment: i think i misreaded *" instead because they let you specify inner content and a separate value="" attribute"* i readed that as you can change the button text with inner html and also with a separated value attribute.. That why i showed you the demo