# How to change an h3 element in HTML using the onclick command in js

Tags: javascript, function, input, onclick, getelementbyid

I've tried a few things but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to make the h3 element change to say, "Hi, (your name)! How are you doing?" when you type your name in the text field and press Enter. I've done onclick commands in the HTML and the code itself. Do I need an `addEventListener`? What am I doing wrong? My code is right here, can you please help? And this is my first time using this as well. Here is the HTML:

```
    <h3 id="h3Id">Hello! What's your name?</h3>
    
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name Here" id="textBox1">
    
    <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="getInputValue()" onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>
```

and this is the javascript:

```
    <script>
        function getInputValue(){
    
        var reply = document.getElementById("textBox1").value;
        
        }
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("h3Id").innerHTML = "Hi, " + reply + "! How are you doing?";
        }
    </script>
```

I've even tried `console.log(reply)` and `console.log('reply')` and even `console.log("reply")` to try to get the value of reply in the console, but it either says reply is undefined(the first one) or just puts reply(the second and third).

Comment: **NOTE** You don't need two separated `onClick` methods .. You can simply --> `onclick="getInputValue(); myFunction();"`

Answer (score 0):

First, you really can't reliably double up on your `onclick` attributes like that; one of them will overwrite the other. You should only have one per element.

Second, take a look at the code below, which is working. Note how I call your `getInputValue()` function from within the `myFunction()` block. I modified `getInputValue()` to return a value that can be used in place of where it's called.

```js
function getInputValue() {
  return document.getElementById("textBox1").value;
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("h3Id").innerHTML = "Hi, " + getInputValue() + "! How are you doing?";
}
```

```html
<h3 id="h3Id">Hello! What's your name?</h3>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name Here" id="textBox1">

<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>
```

Alternatively, this next snippet modifies your original one, but puts the two function calls into the `onclick` attribute for your button.

```js
var reply; //'reply' gets defined globally in this example

function getInputValue() {
  reply = document.getElementById("textBox1").value;
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("h3Id").innerHTML = "Hi, " + reply + "! How are you doing?";
}
```

```html
<h3 id="h3Id">Hello! What's your name?</h3>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name Here" id="textBox1">

<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="getInputValue();myFunction();">Enter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have two functions for onclick. In fact, you can't ([Can an HTML element have the same attribute twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341507/can-an-html-element-have-the-same-attribute-twice))

There are a couple of ways to do this, the first being moving your `document.getElementById("h3Id").innerHTML = "Hi, " + reply + "! How are you doing?";` part into the first function and deleting the second.

```js
function getInputValue(){

  var reply = document.getElementById("textBox1").value;
  document.getElementById("h3Id").innerHTML = "Hi, " + reply + "! How are you doing?";

}
```

```html
    <h3 id="h3Id">Hello! What's your name?</h3>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name Here" id="textBox1">

    <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="getInputValue()">Enter</button>
```

The second would be @Marc's, and the third would be setting reply as `window.reply` instead of `var reply`. There are more, too, but I felt the one I gave a code snippet of is the most concise.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer gives you the correct solution to your problem. But I would like to just point at the concept of "Scope" in JavaScript (which I think is what was causing the problem for you in the first place).

Because you initialized your variable `reply` inside a function, it was not accessible from inside a different function. Variables initialized with keyword `var` are function scoped. Which means if you initialize them inside a function, you cannot access them from outside that function (outer scope).

Reading up on 'local scope' in JS would help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks yall. I´ve been busy so I haven't been able to get back to you right away. I appreciate the help!