# Are there any importance in order of typing HTML attribute/values pair?

Tags: html

I have the code:

```
<input autocomplete="off" autofocus name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
```

[image]

Is there any important of this order in styling or performance?

Comment: maybe depending on how the HTML interpreter is coded, which may have some differences from where it comes, but I doubt there's really any possibility of a performance boostn, which means checking this on every HTML interpreter, on every system, of every brand... (laptops,  Smartphones, tablets...)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no importance in styling or performance. However, it should be noted that if for whatever reason there are conflicting/duplicate tags, [the first one will be prioritized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26341866/11985743).

Answer (score 1):

No, the order doesn't matter. The HTML is parsed into a [DOM structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) before it is rendered.

The only exception is if you use [the same attribute name twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341507/can-an-html-element-have-the-same-attribute-twice).