# Using mulitple checkboxes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there anyway to work with multiple check boxes in MVC. I am getting both true and false values in query string when using the example below.I just want to pass if it was checked True or if it was not checked False.

'http://'webapp':5841/Result/Triggers?**Alcohol=true&Alcohol=false**&Awakening=true&Awakening=false&Coffee=true&Coffee=false'

```
public class Triggers
{
    public string Alcohol { get; set; }
    public string Awakening { get; set; }
    public string Coffee {get; set;}

}



 @using (HTML.BeginForm("Triggers", "Result", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                   '@Html.CheckBox("Alcohol")'

                    '@Html.CheckBox("Awakening")'

                    '@Html.CheckBox("Coffee")'
              }


    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Triggers()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462967/razor-viewengine-html-checkbox-method-creates-a-hidden-input-why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually by design.

The `CheckBox()` (and `RadioButton()`) helper generates a second `<input type="hidden" name="yourName" value="False" />`.

This makes sure that unchecked checkboxes are still sent back to the server for model binding.

If the checkbox is checked, the browser will send two values, and the model binder will use the second one.

Comment: one of the weirdest gotchas in .net mvc.

Comment: so what if i want to use the true value

Comment: @user2224493: The model binder will take care of this automatically.