# MVC Checkbox type="hidden" value not setting to false on uncheck throws " A value is required error"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, hidden

I have list of checkboxes on my view using html helper as below. They are not required field.:-

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m.List1[0].myClass.myValue)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m.List1[1].myClass.myValue)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m.List1[2].myClass.myValue)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m.List1[3].myClass.myValue)
```

with myValue property defined as below in class :-

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool myValue{ get; set; }
```

On form submission the I am getting "A value if required" error for each checkbox. On checking the html page in browser tool. I founf dollowing which seems to be issue: -

```
<input name="List1[0].myClass.myValue" type="hidden" value>
```

I am not sure why this value doesn't even set to false when checkboxes are left un-checked.How can i avoid this validation error of "A value is required".

Comment: i am also having this problem , any news on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

When you put a checkbox in your view, you always get a hidden field with it, acting as a default value when your checkbox is unchecked. See those links for more informations :

- [asp.net mvc: why is Html.CheckBox generating an additional hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input)
- [Razor ViewEngine HTML.Checkbox method creates a hidden input. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462967/razor-viewengine-html-checkbox-method-creates-a-hidden-input-why)

In your code sample (the input element), `value` is not set, is that a typo ?

Also, you should have inputs with `type="checkbox"`, do they appear correctly in your html ?