# Chechbox type Inputs are duplicated in form - Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using "asp-for" helpers to display checkbox type inputs in "get" method form (e.g. `<input type="checkbox" asp-for="BySalary">`). inputs are generating but they are duplicated and when i am sending this form, url is generating incorrectly... 
e.g. `localhost:5001/results?Keyword=&Fulltime=true&BySalary=true&SalaryRange.Range=100%2C10000&Fulltime=false&Parttime=false&Freelance=false&BySalary=false`

```
<form method="get">
some code here
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The BySalary field is required." id="BySalary" name="BySalary" value="true">
some code here
<!-- Search Button / End-->
<input name="Fulltime" type="hidden" value="false"> <-- **here are duplicated inputs**
<input name="Parttime" type="hidden" value="false">
<input name="Fulltime" type="hidden" value="false">
</form>
```

Comment: Please show the code for an  [mcve] that reproduces the behaviour

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MV3 Duplicate Query String Values for CheckBox (true,false for boolean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119569/mv3-duplicate-query-string-values-for-checkbox-true-false-for-boolean)

Comment: See this answer for .Net Core: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65999719