# @Html.CheckBoxFor returns Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

all

I am trying to use @Html.CheckBoxFor.
Here is my code:

Model:

```
public bool WC0001 { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ListSearch", "Committee", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.WC0001)&nbsp;<label for="WC0001" class="mrg_r20">Development</label>
}
```

I am using WebGrid as well.
When I click page 2, I get this error.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

So I looked at the url.
It is "http://localhost:28685/Committee/ListSearch?WC0001=true%2cfalse&page=2"

Why do I get WC0001 parameter as true%2cfalse?
And what is the workaround for this?
It didn't happen when I used to post the form.
But since I changed it as FormMethod.Get because of WebGrid, it started to occur.
Please somebody help me.

EDIT:
[image]

This is what happens, when reload the page.

EDIT:

Here is my action code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ListSearch(Kuksiwon.Models.Committee profile, FormCollection collection)
{
    DataTable _dt = _bp.DtReturnS(false
        , "WSP_KW100_R1"
        , profile.APJIKJONGCODE == null ? "" : profile.APJIKJONGCODE
        , profile.APKUKSICODE == null ? "" : profile.APKUKSICODE
        , profile.CTNAME == null ? "" : profile.CTNAME
        , collection["CTSEXList"] == null ? "" : collection["CTSEXList"].ToString()
        , profile.CTOADDRESS1 == null ? "" : profile.CTOADDRESS1
        , profile.CTOADDRESS2 == null ? "" : profile.CTOADDRESS2
        , profile.CTUNIVCODE1 == null ? "" : profile.CTUNIVCODE1
        , profile.CTHOSPCODE1 == null ? "" : profile.CTHOSPCODE1
        , profile.CTETCNAME == null ? "" : profile.CTETCNAME
        , profile.CTUNIVDIV1 == null ? "" : profile.CTUNIVDIV1
        , profile.CTUNIVJIKUP1 == null ? "" : profile.CTUNIVJIKUP1
        , profile.CTEMAIL == null ? "" : profile.CTEMAIL
        , profile.WC0001 ? "WC0001" : ""
        , profile.WC0002 ? "WC0002" : ""
        , profile.WC0003 ? "WC0003" : ""
        , profile.WC0004 ? "WC0004" : ""
        , profile.WC0005 ? "WC0005" : ""
        , profile.WC0006 ? "WC0006" : ""
        , profile.WC0007 ? "WC0007" : ""
        , profile.WC0008 ? "WC0008" : ""
        , profile.WCNONE ? "1" : "0"
        , profile.RSNAME == null ? "" : profile.RSNAME
        , profile.BKNAME == null ? "" : profile.BKNAME
        , profile.CTSUBJECT == null ? "" : profile.CTSUBJECT
        , profile.CTCOLLEGE == null ? "" : profile.CTCOLLEGE
    );
    ViewBag.ListSearch = _dt;

    profile.CTSEXList = profile.CommonCodeList("SX", "1");
    return View(profile);
}
```

Comment: About the true%2cfalse: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input)

Comment: @hawkke Thanks for your comment. But it still does not help my problem. Any workaround?

Comment: Please post your Action method, because this seems to be the source of your issue.

Comment: @Scott Rippey I have posted my action code.

Comment: `profile.WC0001 ? "WC0001" : ""` are those the bools you are trying to render? Your model shows it is type bool but you are setting the value to a string?

Comment: That means if profile.WC0001 is true, I will pass "WC0001" to stored procedure and if it's not I will pass blank to my stored procedure.

Comment: Is this a BUG from Microsoft ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug (well, I consider it a bug) in what MVC spits out for @Html.CheckBoxFor()-- it spits on the actual input checkbox, but also a hidden field with the same name. They're doing this so that an HTTP post will have the default value (if the checkbox is unchecked) still sent along with the data. But for a GET, the browser is sending both values in the querystring, causing it to come out on the server as a string array (leading to your exception).

Here's the jQuery I ended up using to disable the hidden fields if their checkboxes are checked (disabled fields never get sent via FORM submissions). Stick this in your document ready logic:

```
$('input[type=checkbox] ~ input[type=hidden]').each(function() {
    var curHiddenField = $(this);
    var checkBox = curHiddenField.prev();
    checkBox.change(function () {
        curHiddenField.val(checkBox[0].checked);
        if (checkBox[0].checked) {
            curHiddenField.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            curHiddenField.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason I can think of that would cause this issue is if your `ModelState` were modified with an invalid value.  That would be the only way to get the error while rendering the page.

You should check the `ModelState` in your controller like this:

```
var wc0001 = ModelState["WC0001"].Value;
var raw = wc0001.RawValue; // Should be ["true", "false"]
var attempted = wc0001.AttemptedValue; // Should be "true,false"
var converted = wc0001.ConvertTo(typeof(bool)); // If this fails, then Html.CheckBoxFor will fail too.
```

#### Update:

After looking at your action method, I don't see anything that would cause an invalid `ModelState`.  Please let me know the values of `.RawValue` and `.AttemptedValue` because those will probably have some clue as to the cause of this problem.

Comment: Line 41:     var converted = wc0001.ConvertTo(typeof(bool)); // If this fails, then Html.CheckBoxFor 
Here it returns error. The string cannot be converted to bool.

Comment: The simplest workaround is to clear the ModelState. I also updated my answer with another possible workaround, so maybe one of these will work.

Comment: Could please you tell me how to pass "dummy" parameters to controller? I barely know MVC3.

Comment: I created a test project, and honestly couldn't figure out what could cause your issue.
I'm fairly certain that `wc0001.AttemptedValue` is NOT `"true,false"`, which is why it can't convert to `bool`, but looking at your Action method I don't see anything that would modify the `ModelState`.  
Can you please tell me the `.RawValue` and `.AttemptedValue`?  That might be a clue to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some testing, I think I might have figured out your problem.

As you probably know, rendering a CheckBox results in a an `<input type="checkbox" />` and an `<input type="hidden" />` with the same name.  If the checkbox is checked, when the form is submitted, the GET/POST will have duplicate entries for that field:
`ListSearch?WC0001=true&WC0001=false`
MVC treats these values as an **array of strings** `["true", "false"]`, and when it binds to a `bool`, it only parses the first array item.

You might have already realized the problem now.  Your sample URL has combined these values into:
`ListSearch?WC0001=true,false`
MVC will treat this value as a **single string** `"true,false"`, which means it will FAIL to bind to a `bool`!

The problem is almost certainly caused by some JavaScript that is creating the URL, and the script is probably trying to be smart and combine duplicate inputs into a comma-separated list.  This won't work for MVC, though, so you need to keep the values separate.