# Can't handle AJAX request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Trying to create AJAX request manually. 
On clientside I have something like this:

```
function saveBatterySpecs(id) {
           var url = '@Url.Action("SaveBatterySpecs", "Catalog")';
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: url,
                data: {
                    art: $("#art" + id).val(),
                    brand: $("#brand" + id).val(),
                    name: $("#name" + id).val(),
                    country: $("#country" + id).val(),
                    volt: $("#volt" + id).val(),
                    cap: $("#cap" + id).val(),
                    sp: $("#sp" + id).val(),
                    powc: $("#powc" + id).val(),
                    term: $("#term" + id).val(),
                    mount: $("#mount" + id).val(),
                    adds: $("#adds" + id).val(),
                    length: $("#length" + id).val(),
                    width: $("#width" + id).val(),
                    height: $("#height" + id).val(),
                    guar: $("#guar" + id).val()
                },
                dataType: 'text', //or json, no difference
                success: hideEditForm(id)
            });
```

and on server a simple

```
 public ActionResult SaveBatterySpecs(string batteryData)
            {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                Debug.WriteLine(batteryData);
                return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/EmptyView.cshtml");
                }
            else
                return null;
            }
```

Breakpoint on controller works, all Ok, browser debugger shows normal request with data. But I can't handle that - batteryData is allways null. 
What I'm doing wrong? Solution with forms useless because we avoiding them and can't currently use.
I can switch type from text to json, but this doesn't help.

Comment: you send 15 parameters and you spec 1 in your controller? @maxs87 has the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest what maxs87 brings up, where you post the actual object instead of a string representing the data.

But if you really wanted to accept only a string, you still need the matching variable name:

This will post one parameter called `batteryData`, whose value is a JSON string representing all that data. On the controller, your `batteryData` variable will be populated with a JSON string which you can manually deserialize.

```
data: {
    batteryData: JSON.stringify({
        art: $("#art" + id).val(),
        brand: $("#brand" + id).val(),
        name: $("#name" + id).val(),
    })
},
```

Comment: One thing to watch for - the `JSON` functions are native to recent browsers, but IE6 (and I think IE7) don't have them. If you want to support old browsers, make sure you include [the json2.js library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: Thanks, I think no, but I'll write this tip.

Answer (score 4):

I think its not working because you pass the wrong argument to controller.

try to pass object instead string.

```
 public class BatteryInfo
    {
       public long brand {get;set;}
       public int height {get;set;}
       etc.
    }
```

then recive it in controller

```
ublic ActionResult SaveBatterySpecs(BatteryInfo battery)
```

and why not serialize the form instead of collecting all data from form elements? 
look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json) for details

Comment: 1. I can't use forms, we have only inputs 
2. Trying with BatterySpecs class instead - no result. Will try now with params.