# jquery send all html variable by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass html all tags value to another file using ajax.
is this possible

```
$.ajax({
   url:"myp.php",
   type:'POST',
   data: //here I want to all possible element values in current html
});
```

Any Ideas???

Comment: there are various selectors that you can employ to get all the name value pairs on your page or if you have a form you can serialize the form into name value pairs. What have you tried?

Comment: what do you mean, "element values"? All of the `<input>` and `<textarea>` fields in your page? Look at http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: yes I means <input> and <select>

Comment: -1 because of "I want XYZ" in combination with nothing tried by yourself

Comment: I have tried with each function of body element, but it take long time

Comment: @STT LCU, next time I remind to post all I have tried

Comment: @MandeepSingh that'd be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
   url:"myp.php",
   type:'POST',
   data: $(':input').serialize()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post every possible element values from a special form:

```
$('#myForm').serialize();
```

I think you could do the same with a different selector, which will include every elements to submit:

So, something like this should do the trick:

```
$('input, select, textarea').serialize();
```

You can see here for jQuery.serialize() : http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

And there for similar questions : [Serialize form data to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)

Answer (score 0):

you can post all form's elements using this

```
data : $('#form').serializeArray();
```