# get jQuery form - text value by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a simple html with jQuery form , and i want to:
1) get the value into a js var .
2)send it by JSON to a server .
here is the form :

```
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <data=role "form" name="seekerForm"  id="jobSeekerForm" >
                <label for="basic">First name :</label>
                <input type="text" name="seekerName" id="WfirstName" data-mini="true" />
                <label for="basic">Last name :</label>
                <input type="text" name="seekerLast" id="WlastName" data-mini="true" />
                <label for="basic" id="WEmail">E-mail:</label>
                <input type="text" name="seekerEmail" id="WEmail" data-mini="true" />

            <div data-role="fieldcontain" >
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select" >Choose a field:</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="selectField" >
        <option value="HI-TEC">Software Programming</option>
        <option value="webPro">Web Programming</option>
        <option value="QA">QA</option>
        <option value="systemInfo">System Information</option>
        <option value="DB">DBA</option>
        <option value="java">JAVA</option>
        <option value="c">c++</option>
        <option value="pyt">pyton</option>
    </select>
</div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" >
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select" >Choose Experience level:</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="selectPro" >
        <option value="junior">junior(0-2)</option>
        <option value="senior">senior(2-5)</option>
        <option value="exp">Expert(5-10)</option>
    </select>
                </div>
                </form>
```

3) same thing to the option value .
Here is the way im sending :

// the object i want to send :

```
 var jobsData = {


    name: $name.val(),
            lname: $WlastName.val(),
            mail: $WEmail.val(),
            userlocation: location,
            field : $selectField.val(),
            Pro: $selectPro.val(),
            range: $sliderRange.val() 
    };
    // ajax - data: how i want to send that 

        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'JSON',
          url:'http://localhost:8888',
          data: jobsData,
          success: function(jobs){
              $.each(jobs,function(i,job){
                  $('.jobRes').html(jobs);

              });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`.serialize()`**](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to get all the form values and send them to the server via ajax. Something like this would do:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax( url:'http://localhost:8888/', data: $(this).serialize(),  ..... );
    });
});
```

Your page must be running on the same `localhost` same port `8888` for this to work.

Comment: there is my code : $(function() {var workerInfo = $( "#workerForm" ).serialize(); $( "#jobRes" ).html( workerInfo ); )} ; but it dont get values :seekerName=&seekerLast=&seekerEmail=&select-choice-1=HI-TEC&select-choice-1=jun‌​ior&slider-1=40

Comment: That's because this code is running as soon as the page loads, **before the form is filled**. The code for getting the values **belongs in a submit handler as in the sample I provided**. A submit handler is executed **when** the form is submitted -- hopefully once you fill the form and click the submit button.

Comment: I use : $('#GoButton').click (function () {..} .  thank u , u have helped me very much . should i change that to a form tag? or change it to submit button ?

Comment: You're welcome. When submitting a form it's always recommended to use the `submit` event **on the form** rather than the `click` event **on some button or submit button**. I would use `$('form-selector').submit( .. );`.

Comment: that's working perfect! TY!! u know how to json that string ?

Comment: Would [**`$('form').serializeArray()`**](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) serve your purposes? Or if you want `key/value` format, then take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout the jQuery `.serialize()` method for getting the form values.
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: there is my code : $(function() {   
 var workerInfo = $( "#workerForm" ).serialize();
 $( "#jobRes" ).html( workerInfo ); )} ; but it dont get values :seekerName=&seekerLast=&seekerEmail=&select-choice-1=HI-TEC&select-choice-1=junior&slider-1=40

Comment: try replacing `data=role "form"` with `<form data-role="form">`.  Everything must be inside the form tag you are trying to serialize.

Comment: And its OK to add ID?

Comment: to the `<form>` element?  Sure!