# Getting JSON from elements Jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have this 
**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" required name="article">
    <option value="Coca Cola">Coca Cola</option>
</select>
<input class="form-control number-input" value="" name="qty" type="text">


<select class="form-control" required name="article">
    <option value="Jupi">Jupi</option>
</select>  
<input class="form-control number-input" value="" name="qty" type="text">


<select class="form-control" required name="article">
    <option value="Fanta">Fanta</option>
</select>
<input class="form-control number-input" value="" name="qty" type="text">
```

And

**JS**

```
var invoiceNumber = 1;

var articles = $('[name~=article]').map(function () {
    return $(this).val()
}).get();
var qty = $('[name~=qty]').map(function () {
    return $(this).val()
}).get();
```

What i need is to get new JSON that will look like this

```
var invoicesGet = [{
    "invoice": "1",
    "article": "Coca Cola",
    "qty": "2042"
}, {
    "invoice": "1",
    "article": "Jupi",
    "qty": "232"
}, {
    "invoice": "1",
    "article": "Fanta",
    "qty": "45"
}]
```

This is working fiddle what i have for now:
http://jsfiddle.net/b33kvd3L/

I think i got all elements value, order will be that way, but i dont know how to combine all this json to one, and add invoiceNumber?
I dont know how many inouts will be added they are dinamicly add

Comment: What about this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json like so http://jsfiddle.net/b33kvd3L/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array of objects after your JS:

```
var invoicesGet = [];
for (var i in articles) {
    invoicesGet.push({
        invoice: invoiceNumber,
        article: articles[i],
        qty: qty[i]
    });
}
```

Updated live code: http://jsfiddle.net/b33kvd3L/3/

Produce output like: `[{"invoice":1,"article":"Coca Cola","qty":"12"},{"invoice":1,"article":"Jupi","qty":"34"},{"invoice":1,"article":"Fanta","qty":"56"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Find the next qty input using .next() and return the object then convert to JSON.

```
var articles = $('[name~=article]').map(function () {
    var qtyVal = $(this).next("[name=qty]").val();
    return { 
        invoice: invoiceNumber, 
        article: $(this).val(),
        qty: qtyVal
    };
}).get();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b33kvd3L/16/