# Send form data with jquery ajax json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm new in PHP/jquery
I would like to ask how to send json data from a form field like (name, age, etc) with ajax in a json format. Sadly I can't found any relevant information about this it's even possible to do it dynamically? Google searches only gives back answers like build up the data manually. like: `name: X Y`, `age: 32`, and so on.

Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks for the help!

Edit:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Age: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
FavColor: <input type="text" name="favc"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: please show some codes that you already working on so that we could help you out

Comment: Hi Oli Soproni B. !
Thanks for your comment, my question is edited with the form code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

here is a simple one

here is my test.php for testing only

```
<?php

// this is just a test
//send back to the ajax request the request

echo json_encode($_POST);
```

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form" action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Age: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
FavColor: <input type="text" name="favc"><br>
<input id="submit" type="button" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // click on button submit
        $("#submit").on('click', function(){
            // send ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test.php', // url where to submit the request
                type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
                dataType : 'json', // data type
                data : $("#form").serialize(), // post data || get data
                success : function(result) {
                    // you can see the result from the console
                    // tab of the developer tools
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            })
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Both file are place in the same directory

Comment: The data is posted here as url-encoded form data not json. Please refer to the answer by @Roman Susi

Comment: Not relevant to question. Asker wants to send the form data in JSON. The jQuery in the answer receives Ajax return in JSON instead of sending it in JSON.

Answer (score 24):

The accepted answer here indeed makes a json from a form, but the json contents is really a string with url-encoded contents.

To make a more realistic json POST, use some solution from [Serialize form data to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json) to make `formToJson` function and add `contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'` to the jQuery ajax call parameters.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formToJson($("form")),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    ...
})
```

Comment: I have to say this is the only right answer... all the above are actually posting FORM post contents.  :\  This deserves more upvotes

Comment: Content type is what I missed! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `serialize()` like this:

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  url: 'test.php',
  data: $('form').serialize(),
  datatype: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

  }
});
```

Comment: If you're using `$('form').serialize()` then you don't make data an object; it should just be `data: $('form').serialize(),`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why use JQuery?

Javascript provides FormData api and fetch to perform this easily.

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.onsubmit = function(event){
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    
    fetch("/test.php",
    {
       body: formData,
       method: "post"
    }).then(…);
    
    //Dont submit the form.
    return false; 
}
```

Reference:
https://metamug.com/article/html5/ajax-form-submit.html#submit-form-with-fetch

Answer (score 0):

Sending data from formfields back to the server (php) is usualy done by the POST method which can be found back in the superglobal array $_POST inside PHP. There is no need to transform it to JSON before you send it to the server. Little example:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" value="joe@gmail.com" />
<button type="submit">Send!</button>
```

With AJAX you are able to do exactly the same thing, only without page refresh.