# How to use jquery, json and ajax through html form?

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I need to send a json when a form is filled on html. I have the following html:

```
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
    Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" /> 
    Idade: <input type="number" id="idade" /> 
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

and the following js:

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"
var arr = {
    City : 'Moscow',
    Age : 25
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    //click on button submit
    $("#submit").on('click', function() {
        //send ajax
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/DBRest/rest/escreve',
            type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
            dataType : 'json', // data type
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data : $("#form").serialize(), // post data || get data
            data : JSON.stringify(arr)
        })
    });

});
```

I have already looked for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680562/send-form-data-with-jquery-ajax-json).

I tried creating a `arr` variable to mock a filled form but didn't get anything either. I would like to know the difference between dataType and contentType. And about this specific line:

```
data : $("#form").serialize()
```

is this correct? There's a difference between simple and double quotes surrounding `#form`

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't the form submission? Maybe try `$('#form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); //continue on with what you were doing });` instead of listening for a click on the submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're setting the `data` property twice. Remove `data: JSON.stringify(arr)`.

Secondly, if you send a serialized form it will be `x-www-form-urlencoded`, not JSON, so you should remove the `contentType` property as form encoded is the default.

Then your HTML `input` elements are missing the required `name` attribute which is needed for serialisation and retrieving the values on the server.

```html
Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" /> 
Idade: <input type="number" id="idade" name="idade" />
```

Lastly, you should hook your event handler to the `submit` event of the `form` element and call `preventDefault()` to stop the standard submission, like this:

```
$("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/DBRest/rest/escreve',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $("#form").serialize()
    })
});
```

Presumably you also want `success` and `error` handler functions (or `done()` and `fail()` methods) to handle the response you get back from the request.

Comment: Sorry but that didn't work. Chrome's F12 function didn't show any problem. What I kind of feedback can I show to you? Is there a better way to analyze and debug it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it didn't work'? What are you expecting to happen? Firstly check the request in the network tab of the console and make sure the response code is `200 OK`. Also, as I mentioned you're missing any callback handlers on your AJAX call so the UI won't be updated if that's what you're expecting

Comment: I was getting 415 error and solved it by changing `dataType:'application/json'`. Besides that, didn't changed a bit. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad you solved it. Having to remove that line means that your URL isn't returning JSON - at least not valid JSON anyway

Answer (score 2):

Problem here is, that the form is serialized using `<input name=` parameter. 
E.g.

```
<input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" />
```