# Express Routes not functioning on Single Page Web App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm converting an old LAMP stack project to use Node/Express/MongoDB instead of PHP/Laravel/MySQL. I built out my routes the same way I did in Laravel and have tested the routes I've built using Postman. Every route works as it should through testing in Postman.

However, when I try to use these routes in the display.js file that I wrote, the only route that works is GET /players. I am looking for some insight on these routes and the display file I'm using.

When I click the edit button, my GET /player/:id route grabs the correct information (status code 200 and preview shows JSON object) but will not populate the fields in my form.

When I click the delete button, I get a 404 status code with a response of "Cannot GET /players/123/delete". How do I adjust my display code to use DELETE instead of GET? (I believe I can refactor my all of my routes to just /players/:id using the correct http request method if I can figure out how to pass the request method in the display.js code).

When I try to submit a new record, I get a 400 status code with validation error saying Path `age` is required. It's actually the same error for each field name, so I assume that I'm not passing the values from the field into the JSON object correctly.

I haven't been able to test patch, but believe it should be remedied through fixing DELETE /players/:id and GET /players/:id.

Any help is appreciated. Code is below for display and server js files.

display.js

```
// this is the base url to which all your requests will be made
var baseURL = window.location.origin;
$(document).ready(function(){
// $.ajaxSetup({
//     headers: {
//         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
//     }
// });
$('#table').click(function(event) { // generates the table
    // change the url parameters based on your API here
    // Using an JQuery AJAX GET request to get data form the server
    $.getJSON(baseURL+'/players', function(data) {
        generateTable(data, $('#container'));
    });
});

$('#form').click(function(event) {
    // creating an empty form
    generateForm(null, $('#container'));
});
// Handle table click event for delete
$('#container').on('click', '.delete', function(event) {
    var id = $(this).val();
    // change the url parameters based on your API here
    // remember to create delete functionality on the server side (Model and Controller)
    // Using an JQuery AJAX GET request to get data form the server
    $.getJSON(baseURL+"/players/"+id+"/delete", function(data) {
        //Generate table again after delete
        //change the url based on your API parameters here
        // Using an JQuery AJAX GET request to get data from the server
        $.getJSON(baseURL+'/players', function(data) {
            generateTable(data, $('#container'));
        });
    });
});

// Handle form submit event for both update & create
// if the ID_FIELD is present the server would update the database otherwise the server would create a record in the database
$('#container').on('submit', '#my-form', function(event) {
    var id = $('#id').val();
    console.log(id);
    if (id != "") {
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm(baseURL+"/players/"+id+"/edit", $(this));
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm(baseURL+"/player", $(this));
    }
});

// Handle table click event for edit
// generates form with prefilled values
$('#container').on('click', '.edit', function(event) {
    // getting id to make the AJAX request
    var id = $(this).val();
    // change the url parameters based on your API here
    // Using an JQuery AJAX GET request to get data form the server
    $.getJSON(baseURL+'/players/'+id, function(data) {
        generateForm(data, $('#container'));
    });
});

// function to generate table
function generateTable(data, target) {
    clearContainer(target);
    //Change the table according to your data
    var tableHtml = '<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Position</th><th>Team</th><th>Delete</th><th>Edit</th></tr></thead>';
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
        tableHtml += '<tr><td>'+val.playername+'</td><td>'+val.age+'</td><td>'+val.position+'</td><td>'+val.team+'</td><td><button class="delete" value="'+val._id+'">Delete</button></td><td><button class="edit" value="'+val._id+'">Edit</button></td></tr>';
    });
    tableHtml += '</table>';
    $(target).append(tableHtml);
}

// function to generate form
function generateForm(data, target){
    clearContainer(target);
    //Change form according to your fields
    $(target).append('<form id="my-form"></form>');
    var innerForm = '<fieldset><legend>Player Form</legend><p><label>Player Name: </label>'+'<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id"/>'+'<input type="text" name="playername" id="playername" /></p>' + '<p><label>Age: </label><input type="text" name="age" id="age" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Hometown: </label><input type="text" name="city" id="city" />'+ ' ' + '<input type="text" name="country" id="country" /></p>' + '<p><label>Gender: </label><input type="text" name="gender" id="gender" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Handedness: </label><input type="text" name="handedness" id="handedness" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Broom: </label><input type="text" name="broom" id="broom" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Position: </label><input type="text" name="position" id="position" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Team: </label><input type="text" name="team" id="team" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Favorite Color: </label><input type="text" name="favoritecolor" id="favoritecolor" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Headshot: </label><input type="text" name="headshot" id="Headshot" /></p>'+ '<input type="submit"/>';
    $('#my-form').append(innerForm);
    //Change values according to your data
    if(data != null){
        $.each(data, function(index, val) {
            $('#id').val(val._id);
            $('#playername').val(val.playername);
            $('#age').val(val.age);
            $('#city').val(val.city);
            $('#country').val(val.country);
            $('#gender').val(val.gender);
            $('#handedness').val(val.handedness);
            $('#broom').val(val.broom);
            $('#position').val(val.position);
            $('#team').val(val.team);
            $('#favoritecolor').val(val.favoritecolor);
            $('#Headshot').val(val.headshot);
        });
    }
}

function submitForm(url, form){
    $.post(url, form.serialize(), function(data) {
        showNotification(data, $('#notification'));
    });
}

function showNotification(data, target){
    clearContainer(target);
    target.append('<p>'+data+'</p>');
}

function clearContainer(container){
    container.html('');
}
});
```

server.js

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
var {Player} = require('./models/player');

var app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'./../public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.post('/player', (req, res) => {
  var player = new Player({
    playername: req.body.playername,
    age: req.body.age,
    city: req.body.city,
    country: req.body.country,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    handedness: req.body.handedness,
    broom: req.body.broom,
    position: req.body.position,
    team: req.body.team,
    favoritecolor: req.body.favoritecolor,
    headshot: req.body.headshot
  });
  player.save().then((doc) => {
    res.send(doc);
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  });
});

app.get('/players', (req, res) => {
  Player.find().then((players) => {
    res.send(players);
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  });
});

app.get('/players/:id', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }
  Player.findById(id).then((player) => {
    if (player) {
      res.send(player);
    } else {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  });
});

app.delete('/players/:id/delete', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }
  Player.findByIdAndRemove(id).then((player) => {
    if (player) {
      res.send(player);
    } else {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  });
});

app.patch('/players/:id/edit', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var body = _.pick(req.body, ['playername', 'age', 'city', 'country', 'gender', 'handedness', 'broom', 'position', 'team', 'favoritecolor', 'headshot']);
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }
  Player.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: body}, {new: true}).then((player) => {
    if (!player) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    } else {
      res.send(player);
    }
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  })
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Started on port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = {app};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I click the delete button, I get a 404 status code with a response of "Cannot GET /players/123/delete". How do I adjust my display code to use DELETE instead of GET? (I believe I can refactor my all of my routes to just /players/:id using the correct http request method if I can figure out how to pass the request method in the display.js code).

This is because your app has `app.delete('/players/:id/delete')` and not `app.get('/players/:id/delete')`. However, your server side code shouldn't change much, just one tweak:

- If you have an `app.delete()` then really no need to have the verb `delete` at the end of the resource.

Also you need to make the request using the HTTP Method `DELETE` instead of making a `GET` in `display.js`. Just make the `DELETE` request using `$.ajax()` with  `type` set to `'DELETE'`

> When I click the edit button, my GET /player/:id route grabs the correct information (status code 200 and preview shows JSON object) but will not populate the fields in my form.

This is because your implementation of `$.each()` assumes `data` will always be an Array and not ever and object, however, your `generateForm()` is passing in a Player object. Change your `$.each()` to do type checking for array handling and object handling. See below changes.

> When I try to submit a new record, I get a 400 status code with validation error saying Path age is required. It's actually the same error for each field name, so I assume that I'm not passing the values from the field into the JSON object correctly.

If you make the above change to `generateForm()` it should fix this.

---

Just take the below snippets and replace those sections within your app, it should work.

#### server.js

```
app.delete('/players/:id', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }
  return Player.findByIdAndRemove(id).then((player) => {
    if (player) {
      res.status(200).json(player);
    } else {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  });
});

app.patch('/players/:id', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var body = _.pick(req.body, ['playername', 'age', 'city', 'country', 'gender', 'handedness', 'broom', 'position', 'team', 'favoritecolor', 'headshot']);
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }
  Player.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: body}, {new: true}).then((player) => {
    if (!player) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(player);
    }
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  })
});

app.post('/players', (req, res) => {
  var player = new Player({
    playername: req.body.playername,
    age: req.body.age,
    city: req.body.city,
    country: req.body.country,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    handedness: req.body.handedness,
    broom: req.body.broom,
    position: req.body.position,
    team: req.body.team,
    favoritecolor: req.body.favoritecolor,
    headshot: req.body.headshot
  });

  return player.save().then((doc) => {
    return res.status(200).json(doc);
  }, (e) => {a
    return res.status(400).send(e);
  });
});
```

#### display.js

```
// Handle form submit event for both update & create
// if the ID_FIELD is present the server would update the database otherwise the server would create a record in the database
$('#container').on('submit', '#my-form', function(event) {
    var id = $('#id').val();
    let formData = {};

    $.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(_, kv) {
          if (formData.hasOwnProperty(kv.name)) {
            formData[kv.name] = $.makeArray(formData[kv.name]);
            formData[kv.name].push(kv.value);
          }
          else {
            formData[kv.name] = kv.value;
          }
        });

    console.log(id);
    if (id != "") {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: baseURL + '/players/' + id,
            type: 'PATCH',
            success: function(edited) {
                // Handle returned edited player
            }
        })
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: baseURL + '/players',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(created) {
              // Handle created player
            }
        })
    }
});

// Handle table click event for delete
$('#container').on('click', '.delete', function(event) {
    var id = $(this).val();
    // change the url parameters based on your API here
    // remember to create delete functionality on the server side (Model and Controller)
    // Using an JQuery AJAX GET request to get data form the server
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL + '/players/' + id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(data) {
          //Generate table again after delete
        //change the url based on your API parameters here
        // Using an JQuery AJAX GET request to get data from the server
        $.getJSON(baseURL+'/players', function(data) {
            generateTable(data, $('#container'));
        });
        }
    });
});

// function to generate form
function generateForm(data, target){
    clearContainer(target);
    //Change form according to your fields
    $(target).append('<form id="my-form"></form>');
    var innerForm = '<fieldset><legend>Player Form</legend><p><label>Player Name: </label>'+'<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id"/>'+'<input type="text" name="playername" id="playername" /></p>' + '<p><label>Age: </label><input type="text" name="age" id="age" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Hometown: </label><input type="text" name="city" id="city" />'+ ' ' + '<input type="text" name="country" id="country" /></p>' + '<p><label>Gender: </label><input type="text" name="gender" id="gender" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Handedness: </label><input type="text" name="handedness" id="handedness" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Broom: </label><input type="text" name="broom" id="broom" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Position: </label><input type="text" name="position" id="position" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Team: </label><input type="text" name="team" id="team" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Favorite Color: </label><input type="text" name="favoritecolor" id="favoritecolor" /></p>'+ '<p><label>Headshot: </label><input type="text" name="headshot" id="Headshot" /></p>'+ '<input type="submit"/>';
    $('#my-form').append(innerForm);

    //Change values according to your data
    if(data instanceof Array){
        $.each(data, function(index, val) {
            $('#id').val(val._id);
            $('#playername').val(val.playername);
            $('#age').val(val.age);
            $('#city').val(val.city);
            $('#country').val(val.country);
            $('#gender').val(val.gender);
            $('#handedness').val(val.handedness);
            $('#broom').val(val.broom);
            $('#position').val(val.position);
            $('#team').val(val.team);
            $('#favoritecolor').val(val.favoritecolor);
            $('#Headshot').val(val.headshot);
        });
    }
    else if (typeof data === 'object') {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) => {
            $('#' + key).val(value);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely fixes the DELETE issue. Thanks! JSON object issue, when using JSON.parse() I get a SyntaxError that says "unexpected token o in json at position 1". Could it be that I need to use JSON.stringify() instead? When attempting that, the app moves from the table to the form, but produces a TypeError that says "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in...". Thoughts?

Comment: @SepticReVo try replacing all the places where you doing `res.send()` with `res.status(200).json()` when a successful action occurs. This will guarantee that the `Content-Type` header will be set to `application/json`. All responses are strings, that is why you need to do JSON.parse(). Doing `JSON.stringify()` on a JSON string will just result in a doubly Stringified JSON value.

Comment: No change. JSON.parse() still gives the syntax error and JSON.stringify() still gives the TypeError.

Comment: @SepticReVo see my edits for `$.each()`, Also removed my `JSON.parse()` stuff because I didn't realize `$.getJSON()` implicitly converts JSON to a JS Object.

Comment: That solves my GET /players/id issue. Thanks! I still get the 400 issue when I make a PATCH or POST requests. I realized that the value for the hidden id in the form is id and not _id, but still no dice in working overall.

Comment: @SepticReVo thats because you're using `submitForm()` and that won't use `PATCH` and you don't have a `method` attribute on your `<form>`. Switch to using the `$.ajax()` approach for these things as well. See my updates to both `display.js` and `server.js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137087/discussion-between-septicrevo-and-peteb).

Answer (score 0):

Try `res.json(player);` instead of `res.send(player);` in order to send the data in JSON format.

Also, instead of `$.post(url, form.serialize(), function(data) {`try the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30680773/1955940) in order to send the data in JSON format.