# Convert form fields into JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have the following form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST">        
    <input type="text" name="matrix[]" value="1"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="matrix[]" value="2"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="matrix[]" value="3"/><br/>     
    <input type="text" name="multi_matrix[colors][]" value="red"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="multi_matrix[colors][]" value="blue"/><br/>        
    <input type="text" name="multi_matrix[weight][]" value="75"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="multi_matrix[weight][]" value="83"/><br/>      
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

now I want to use JavaScript/jQuery to convert those values into JSON string. When I use JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray()) code then it returns the following:

```
[{"name":"matrix[]","value":"1"},{"name":"matrix[]","value":"2"},{"name":"matrix[]","value":"3"},{"name":"multi_matrix[colors][]","value":"red"},{"name":"multi_matrix[colors][]","value":"blue"},{"name":"multi_matrix[weight][]","value":"75"},{"name":"multi_matrix[weight][]","value":"83"}]
```

as you can see all fields have a separate entry, but I want to join them together to get the following:

```
{"matrix":[1,2,3],"multi_matrix":{"colors":["red","blue"],"weight":[75,83]}}
```

Is there any built-in function that can do this ? Or do I have to iterate through all fields and create JSON manually on my own ?

Comment: Sorry, my answer was incorrect. Look at the second answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json

Comment: jQurey("#myForm").serialize()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Comment: Thank you, the solution posted in linked topic seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend jQuery and create a UDF serializeObject like done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery#1186309), based on the [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/):

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

My variant:

```js
arr = $("#myForm").serializeArray();

var res={};
var m,o;
arr.forEach(function(item){
 m = item.name.match(/[^\]\[]+/g);
 o = res;
 m.forEach(function(v,i,a){
  if(o[v] === undefined) {
   if(i+1 !== a.length) {
    o[v] = {};
    o = o[v];
    return;
   }
   o[v] = [item.value];
  } else {
   if(i+1 !== a.length) {
    o = o[v];
    return;
   }
   o[v].push(item.value);
  }
 });
})

console.log(res)
$('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(res)+'</pre>').appendTo('#result')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form id="myForm" method="POST">        
    <input type="text" name="matrix[]" value="1"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="matrix[]" value="2"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="matrix[]" value="3"/><br/>     
    <input type="text" name="multi_matrix[colors][]" value="red"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="multi_matrix[colors][]" value="blue"/><br/>        
    <input type="text" name="multi_matrix[weight][]" value="75"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="multi_matrix[weight][]" value="83"/><br/>     
    <input type="text" name="multi_matrix[weight_real][]" value="83.32"/><br/>   
    <input type="text" name="multi_matrix[weight_real][]" value="83.65"/><br/>       
    <input type="text" name="multi_matrix[price][unreal][]" value="383.32"/><br/>   
    <input type="text" name="multi_matrix[price][unreal][]" value="183.65"/><br/>    
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```
{
    "matrix": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "multi_matrix": {
        "colors": ["red", "blue"],
        "weight": ["75", "83"],
        "weight_real": ["83.32", "83.65"],
        "price": {
            "unreal": ["383.32", "183.65"]
        }
    }
}
```