# How to Serialize MVC form into JSON in Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to Serialize my MVC form to JSON using JQuery and then want to Deserialize some values like value of input field at backend in C# but i am unable to serialize it in json...Please help me in this issue.following is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#btnsearch').click(function (e) {

            var searchname = $('#txtsearch').val();

            var form = $(this).serializeArray();

            DrawTable(form);
        });



        function DrawTable() {
            var props = [];
            props.push({ name: "FirstName", value: firstname });
            BindDataTable({ AllowPaging: true, ShowFilter: false, ShowEditLink: true, EmptyTableText: 'No Data Found', SortIndex: 0, SortDirection: "asc" },
                              "#tblCustomers",
                              "@Url.Action("GetAllCustomers", "Customer")",
                              props,
                              [{ name: "Id", cellClass: "alignCenter", Sortable: true, index: 0 }, { name: "FirstName" }, { name: "ABN" }, { name: "Phone" }, { name: "Email" }, { name: "Address1" }, { name: "City" }, { name: "Country" }],
                              [{ name: "Id", type: "anchor", title: 'customerTable', viewtitle: 'View', link: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Customer")', index: 0 }]);

        } 

       // DrawTable(data);
        //$('#myInputTextField').on('keyup', function () {
        //    oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
        //});



    });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's a very old question and there is a lot of similar questions with answers:

- [Serialize form data to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774)
- [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624)

But this is asking specifically for Asp.MVC: I have tested most of the answers and they fail to serialize forms encoded the way Asp.mvc works, **when there are property of list type** that Asp.MVC forms encodes as

```
   TheProperty[1].SubProperty=Value
   TheProperty[2].SubProperty=Value
```

The only serializer that treats that case correctly is [this](https://github.com/raphaelm22/jquery.serializeToJSON), when configured with the option

```
{ associativeArrays: false }
```

(thanks raphaelm22 for your solution!)

Comment: Been searching for this for hours, thank you! Posting ASP.NET form arrays to a JSON endpoint is impossible without this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$(this).serializeArray();` because `this` refers to `$('#btnsearch')`, which is not a form.

Use `$("#your_form_id).serializeArray();` or `$("#your_form_id).serialize()`.

Comment: can you please tell me that how to deserialize it in c# and get specific value from it like i want to get text that i entered in textbox

Comment: Or better: `$(this).closest("form").serializeArray()`, this way, you don't need to know (or even have) the id of the form.

Comment: @AhmadCheema - there are a lot of good answers on StackOverflow how to deserialize JSON to strongly typed object.

Comment: @Riokmij after serializing i got this: form = "__RequestVerificationToken=tYY7hJDUAgtisu8r8dB4VxwFhJb2m8JRPz_bIgbmJhgZjLQp6Sf-lnQE2x3TG9BNCc4B-PTPAU9TewJNUP_d6kgK8TUIej2fiPkWAiImu_Y1"   is it serialized correctly ?