# How to convert form data into JSON (Beginner) in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to send data using AJAX to PHP page. I am getting all the data from the form and I am trying to convert it to JSON. However, `.stringify()` doesn't do the job for me.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            console.log("Ready..");

            $("#profile-form").submit(function(event){
                var data = $(this).serialize();
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                $.ajax({
                    type    : "POST",
                    url     : "profile.php",
                    data    : JSON.stringify(data),
                    success : function(response){
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });

            //$("#profile-form").submit();
        });
</script>
```

I am able to see the form-data on the console. However, I am not getting any JSON data on the server. I have just done `print_r($_POST['data'])` in my `profile.php` page. However, it says variable data not defined.

Comment: This isn't going to send json to server. Show how you are trying to receive in your php. There is no point in using JSON.stringify when `serialize()` returns a form encoded string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no `$_POST['data']` available because the data you are sending is saved directly in `$_POST` variable, which should be accessible with `print_r($_POST)` or `print_r(json_decode(print_r($_POST)))` (since you have stringified it.)

Comment: However I have one query. I am able to see all my form data in the address bar. How do I clear it after I get the response? I tried location.reload() however it did'nt work.

Comment: Which data you are talking about?

Comment: The form data which I sent thro my html form and then I got a response from Ajax. However, I am still able to see my form data in the URL. Even though I am sending data using POST

Comment: I am not yet sure about the reason for this. But you can try not to use `JSON.stringify`. Just send like `data    : data` and you can get the data from `$_POST` without `json_decode`

Answer (score 3):

since you already serialize your data. no need to use JSON.stringify it.
also add an option `dataType : json`

```
$.ajax({
    type    : "POST",
    url     : "profile.php",
    data    : data,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

also on your PHP.  you should do

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: this `dataType` is actually for "The type of data that you're expecting back from the server."  So it doesn't relate to his problem.

Comment: @roullie It gives me a XHR failed loading:..  I can see the form data. However, I am not getting any response.

Comment: @roullie data type json doesnt work.. however, when I removed the datatype: json. It showed me my response. Thanks for the imitation

Answer (score -1):

According to [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/),

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.

Just something like `single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1`

It is not what you want, actually.

You can simply generate a JavaScript object and serialize it:

```
$.ajax({
    type     : "POST",
    url      : "profile.php",
    data     : 'data=' + JSON.stringify({
        "name": $("#name").val(),
        "password": $("#password").val()
    })
}).done(function(dt) {
});
```

At the server-side, `$_POST['data']` will contain the JSON representation of your form.

It may be automated. Read these articles on how to do the universal solution:

[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)
[Serialize form data to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)

Comment: and why wouldn't it be what is wanted? Your object will be converted to exactly the same format. `dataType` only tells jQuery what to expect in response

Comment: @charlietfl This AJAX converts the OP's form into JSON and sends to the server. Why doesn't it makes sense? `serialize` is not a function which should be used in this case.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with using serialize to send data. Unless you send this json with appropriate content type, $_POST will be empty at server since you aren't send key/value pair