# how to get form field value and send to server as json using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have search form with 6 fields and 1 search button. when user fill the form deatails and click on search button, i need to send the form field values as json to server using jquery ajax.

then the server will send the search values and returns the response, then i need to populate those valuse in ui.  i need sample UI code for jquery ajax .  please can anyone help on this?
below is my html form

```
<form name="NAME" id="customerDetailSearchForm" action="">
  <fieldset>
     <legend>Search Contact</legend>
     <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="vzuui-detailpanel">
        <tr>
           <td><label>Name :</label><input type="text" value="" /></td>
           <td><label>City :</label><input type="text" value="" /></td>
           <td><label>Phone :</label><input type="text" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><label>Address :</label><input type="text" value="" /></td>
           <td><label>State Prov :</label><input type="text" value="" /></td>
           <td><label>Email :</label><input type="text" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </fieldset>
   <button class="vzuui-btn-red-active closeedit" type="button" id="search">Search</button>
```

Comment: `$('#customerDetailSearchForm').serialize()` will grab all the `data` from `form`

Comment: $('#customerDetailSearchForm').serialize() stored into single variable and send to server

Comment: [Serialize form data to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)

Comment: ok. i need sample ajax code for hit the sevice. can u give me the sample ajax code to hit the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you will need to change you HTML form code to include `name` attribute in the textfields like below

```
<form name="NAME" id="customerDetailSearchForm" action="">
  <fieldset>
     <legend>Search Contact</legend>
     <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="vzuui-detailpanel">
        <tr>
           <td><label>Name :</label><input type="text" value="" name="name" /></td>
           <td><label>City :</label><input type="text" value="" name="city" /></td>
           <td><label>Phone :</label><input type="text" value="" name="phone" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><label>Address :</label><input type="text" value="" name="address" /></td>
           <td><label>State Prov :</label><input type="text" value="" name="state" /></td>
           <td><label>Email :</label><input type="text" value="" name="email" /></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </fieldset>
   <button class="vzuui-btn-red-active closeedit" type="button" id="search">Search</button>
```

This is required because we will be using `jQuery serializeArray() Method` which `creates an array of objects (name and value) by serializing form values.`

Now the jQuery part to form the JSON data from your form and make the AJAX call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").click(function(){

     var frm = $("customerDetailSearchForm").serializeArray();
      var obj = {};
      for (var a = 0; a < frm.length; a++) {
         obj[frm[a].name] = frm[a].value;
      }
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);

    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'http://example.com', 
        data: jsonData , 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
           // add result to UI code over here
        }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**

The above javascript snippet edited to generate proper JSON value

Comment: Hi Aniket,  
i have implemented ur code but im getting error. 
json value also not coming properly when i use  var jsonData = JSON.stringify(frm);

Console Error:                                                                                                
http://url.com?[{"name":"name","value":"jhon"},{"name":"city","value":"us"},{"name":"phone","value":"9897896581"},{"name":"address","value":"Colianielna"},{"name":"state","value":"Ustance"},{"name":"email","value":"jhon@domain.com"}] 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Hello Ganesh, the code that I shared uses GET method.. You can see that I mentioned it as type: 'GET'. HTTP 405 error means you are using the wrong method, so I assume maybe the service that you are calling uses POST method. Confirm the same and use the appropriate method accordingly. As for the improper JSON value check my edited answer

Comment: Hi Aniket, i made those changes now it is working fine. Thanks for helping me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can I use this approach for POST method?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

But before that you have to add `name` attribute for each input element.

So that name will be your json key and the data in the box will be value of that key as below

`<input name='username' value='' />`

Will become

`{"username": "john"}`

jhon is value entered in input box.

**edit (Ajax code) **

```
$(function() {
    $('#customerDetailSearchForm').submit(function() {
     $.post("//your URL here",JSON.stringify($('#customerDetailSearchForm').serializeObject()), function(result){

        alert("Data posted successfully!!");

    });
  });
});
```

or replace below line if you dont have submit button in the form

```
$('#customerDetailSearchForm').submit(function() {
```

with

```
$('#search').click(function() {
```

Comment: ok. i need sample ajax code for hit the sevice. can u give me the sample ajax code to hit the service

Comment: Amended in the post, try it

Comment: Hi All.  I have used @Aniket code. Now it is working fine. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple Ajax Code that I use in Asp.net MVC
I think This will help you,

```
$.ajax({
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    AjaxRequestStart();
                },
                error: function (result) {
                                     },
                complete: function () {
                    AjaxRequestFinish();
                },
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Project/SaveProject")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#frmAddProject').serialize(),
                success: function (result) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i agree with @Aniket. add name first for each input type.

```
<form name="NAME" id="customerDetailSearchForm" action="your_url">
  <fieldset>
     <legend>Search Contact</legend>
     <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="vzuui-detailpanel">
        <tr>
           <td><label>Name :</label><input type="text" value="" name="name" /></td>
           <td><label>City :</label><input type="text" value="" name="city" /></td>
           <td><label>Phone :</label><input type="text" value="" name="phone" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><label>Address :</label><input type="text" value="" name="address" /></td>
           <td><label>State Prov :</label><input type="text" value="" name="state" /></td>
           <td><label>Email :</label><input type="text" value="" name="email" /></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </fieldset>
   <button class="vzuui-btn-red-active closeedit" onclick="_submit();" type="button" id="search">Search</button>
```

For calling ajax, you can use this.

```
function _submit{
       $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'your_url',
                data: $("#customerDetailSearchForm").serialize(),
                success: function(responseData, textStatus) {
                    // you implementation logic here
                },
                complete: function(textStatus) {

                },
                error: function(responseData)
                {

                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below sample ajax call on form submit

```
    $("#customerDetailSearchForm").submit(function(e) {

             var postData = $('#conatctUs').serializeArray();
             var formURL = $('#conatctUs').attr("action");
             var formName  = $('#conatctUs').attr('name');

             $.ajax({
                    url : formURL,
                    type: "POST",
                    data : postData,
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        if(data.status){
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {

                    }


            e.preventDefault(); 
    });
```