# Collect form all inputs data into structured json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I'm trying to collect html form inputs to JSON.

I was trying to realize it with jQuery `serializeArray` which works ok for simple input names, but in case I have multidimensional inputs name like

```
<input type="text" name="product[0][name]" >
```

as an output of `serializeArray` I have list of object like

```
var result = $('#myform').serializeArray();
console.log( result );

0: Object
   name: "product[0][name]"
   value: "product 1"
   ...
1: Object
   name: "product[1][name]"
   value: "product 2"
   ...
...
```

also tried with `JSON.stringify($('#myform').serializeArray());` but oputput again contain concated names as keys

```
[{"name":"product[0][name]","value":"product 1"}, ...
```

But I would like to parse it or use some other know function from jQuery or other library which will give me output in this way

```
{
  product: [
      0: {'name':'product 1'},
      1: {'name':'product 1'},
      2: {'name':'product 1'},
  ],
  some_other_filed: [
      0: {'key':'value'},
      1: {'name':'value'}
  ]
}
```

Dose anyone know solution for this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize form data to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)

Comment: @OleViaud-Murat actually i tested it already with `JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());` it gives same names as output in json {"name":"product[0][name]","value":"Product"} but i need to have it separated as i mentioned in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery [`serializeJSON` plugin](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON/blob/master/jquery.serializejson.min.js).

```
$('#myform').serializeJSON();
console.log( result );
```

Comment: Yes that was exactly what i was looking for, Thank you @AlessioCantarella