# Trouble with Json stringify and serializeArray

Tags: javascript, html, json, serialization, forms

I'm having a Json problem when using serializeArray.

I have an HTML form like :

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myForm">
ID: <input type="text" name="id" /><br/>
State (XX): <input type="text" name="state" /><br/>
<p><input type="submit" onClick='submitform()' /></p>
</form>
```

With this in javascript:

```
function submitform() {
var formData = JSON.stringify($("form[name*='myForm']").serializeArray());
alert(formData);
```

The alert is outputting in name value pairs like:

[{"name":"id","value":"1234"},{"name":"state","value":"CA"}

What I really want is to output:
{"id":"1234","state":"CA"}

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow already has allot of posts on these

[Serialize form data to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)

```
   $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
```