# Serialize form data into array notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, http, serialization

I have this form

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="one" value="somevalue">
  <input type="hidden" name="two" value="anothervalue">
  <input type="hidden" name="three" value="someothervalue">
</form>
```

I also can use jQuery.

How can i serialize the form data to get the `$.post()` or `$.ajax()` methods to send the data in the HTTP request this way:

```
mydata[one]: somevalue
mydata[two]: anothervalue
mydata[three]: someothervalue
```

Instead of:

```
one: somevalue
two: anothervalue
three: someothervalue
```

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1) set the name directly:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mydata[one]" value="somevalue">
```

2) change the form's names after load (if you want some dynamic behavior). Something like that (not tested):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var prefix = 'data'; //or get from some data- attribute
    $('form input').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('name', prefix + '[' + $(this).attr('name') + ']' );
    });
});
```

Then, if you want to send your data via AJAX+jQuery, one approach is to serialize your form data with [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Comment: Yeah, 2nd choice is what i finally used. I can't modify the source HTML form, that's why i needed a client side solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send an array through `$.ajax()`, but you can send a JSON string. So, something like this would work:

```
var frm = $(document.myform);
var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
```

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     url: targetURL,
    data: JSON.stringify($('#form').serializeArray())
})
.done(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      return true;
})
.complete(function() {})
.error(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log('ajax loading error...');
     return false;
    }
});
```

---

On PHP side, use `json_decode` to turn the JSON back into an array:

```
// decode JSON string to PHP object, 2nd param sets to associative array
$decoded = json_decode($_REQUEST['data'],true);

output values:
foreach ($decoded as $value) {
   echo $value["name"] . "=" . $value["value"];
}
```

---

References:

https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-php-ajax-json/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11338832/1447509

https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/bynaK/

Comment: Cool, i forgot to tell i needed a client side solution. mrlew pointed to the right direction. Thanks anyway man.