# Is it possible to populate an Object instance by looping through an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm making a journal app and need to create an object instance every time inputs are submitted on my html form.

I want to create a loop that takes the inputs in results and converts them to values in a new Object instance. My attempt at this so far gives me an instance with undefined values however. Is this even possible to do?

```
results = []

function example(a, b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

function getElements(){
var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
results.push(a,b)
}
```

My attempt at a loop to create a new instance of example

```
function createNewDay(){
    for (i = 0;i<results.length;i++){
    var x = new day([i])
    }
}
```

When I console.log => example{a:undefined, b:undefined}

Comment: Of course it is. you're probably just doing it wrong, but i can't tell given the code in your question... it's a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish with it. You created a new instance of `day` on each iteration, but did nothing with it, and that sample doesn't seem to have anything to do with the console.log result..

Comment: I'm not completely following you but did you mean to do `results.push(new example(a, b))` and `new day(results[i])`?

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do it create a new journal entry every time a "submit" button is clicked on an html form. This journal entry would be a new Object instance. I'm new to programming so this probably isn't the best way, but my reasoning is to push the values to results and then loop through results and make each one a separate property of the new Object instance. So if results = [1,2] then I want the Object instance to look like this => object{a: 1, b:2}

Comment: You never call `example`. How does it relate to your question?

Comment: I call it in my original code, sorry I didn't include it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="a" type="text">
  <input id="b" type="text">
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" id="view">View results in console</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var results = [];

function Example(a, b) {a
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}

function getElements() {
 var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
 var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
 results.push(new Example(a, b));
}

function loopResults() {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    console.log(results[i]);
  }
}

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', getElements, false);
document.getElementById('view').addEventListener('click', loopResults, false);
</script>
</html>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/jehupayomu/1/

Comment: Thank you! This is so simple, I'm kicking myself for not thinking of it.

Answer (score 0):

So... you can use jquery for that:

```
var formDataObject = $("refer_to_form_by_id_or_name").serializeObject();
```

Like mentioned in here: [Serialize form data to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)

Comment: This question does not include the `jQuery` tag, hence a pure JavaScript solution is expected.

Comment: perhaps. perhaps  author is unaware that some libraries may be helpful here. it wasn't precisely stated that vanilla js solution is wanted. if author will make it clear, I can delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FormData` for this -- which makes it a more general solution:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

form.onsubmit = function () {
    var formdata = new FormData(this);
    var results = {};
    for ([key, value] of formdata) {
        results[key] = value;
    }
    console.log(results);
    return false; // cancel submission
};
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
    a: <input name="a" value=""><br>
    b: <input name="b" value=""><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```