# How to convert HTML data attribute to JSON in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I use JSON in hidden element in HTML to avoid multiple unnecessary AJAX requests. JSON is generated properly but I can't handle it using JQuery so I can work with it.

The problem is that `elem.data("json")` returns an object instead of string so `parseJSON` says that there is unexpected o at the start of the string.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log($('#locations-json').data('json'));   
    console.log(JSON.parse($('#locations-json').data('json'))); # tried parseJSON
    $('.class-destination-from').change(function () {
        $.when(get_destination_from_state(),function(res){
            //if (res=='city'){
            //
            //}elif(res=='airport'){
            //    pass
            //}elif(res=='empty'){
            //    pass
            //}
        });
    })
});
```

**CONSOLE**

> Object {cities: "[1, 2, 3, 4]", airports: "[5, 6]"} VM1345:1 Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

This is the part of HTML:

```
<div id="locations-json" data-json="{&quot;cities&quot;: &quot;[1, 2, 3, 4]&quot;, &quot;airports&quot;: &quot;[5, 6]&quot;}" style="display: none"></div>
```

Do you know how to convert it properly?

Comment: JSON objects must have quoted keys: `{ "cities": "[1, 2, 3, 4]", "airports": "[5, 6]"}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize form data to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've added the element at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, as it so often is, is that [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) isn't what most people think it is. `data` is **not** an accessor for `data-*` properties, it's both more and less than that. It manages jQuery's internal data cache for the element. It *initializes* that cache from `data-*` attributes, but it duplicates the data in the cache, processes the data, and never writes back to the attributes.

It's that "processing the data" that's hitting you in this case: `data` automatically detects that what you're reading is JSON and parses it *for you*. So you'll get back an object, and don't need to parse it.

So using `data`:

```js
var locations = $("#locations-json").data("json");
console.log(locations);
console.log("There are " + locations.cities.length + " cities");
```

```html
<div id="locations-json" data-json="{&quot;cities&quot;: &quot;[1, 2, 3, 4]&quot;, &quot;airports&quot;: &quot;[5, 6]&quot;}" style="display: none"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you noted in a comment, that says there are 12 cities. That's because the JSON gives `cities` (and `airports`) a **string** value:

```
{"cities": "[1, 2, 3, 4]", "airports": "[5, 6]"}
```

You probably meant the JSON to be:

```
{"cities": [1, 2, 3, 4], "airports": [5, 6]}
```

Example:

```js
var locations = $("#locations-json").data("json");
console.log(locations);
console.log("There are " + locations.cities.length + " cities");
```

```html
<div id="locations-json" data-json="{&quot;cities&quot;: [1, 2, 3, 4], &quot;airports&quot;: [5, 6]}" style="display: none"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

But unless you need the various features of `data`, just use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) and parse yourself:

```js
var locations = JSON.parse($("#locations-json").attr("data-json"));
console.log(locations);
console.log("There are " + locations.cities.length + " cities");
```

```html
<div id="locations-json" data-json="{&quot;cities&quot;: [1, 2, 3, 4], &quot;airports&quot;: [5, 6]}" style="display: none"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Note:

As of [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39787480/2), your question had a valid `div` that looked like this:

```
<div id="locations-json" data-json="{&quot;cities&quot;: &quot;[1, 2, 3, 4]&quot;, &quot;airports&quot;: &quot;[5, 6]&quot;}" style="display: none"></div>
```

But then [you edited it again](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39787480/3) to look like this, which is invalid:

```
<div id="locations-json" data-json="{"cities": "[1, 2, 3, 4]", "airports": "[5, 6]"}" style="display: none"></div>
```

The version with `&quot;` is correct, be sure to use that.

Comment: I'm not sure if it parses the JSON correctly but I'm new in this area so It could be correct. When I do: $('#locations-json').data('json').cities it returns [1, 2, 3, 4] which is correct. But when I try to get the first city - so 1 - it returns "[" like it thinks that the array is a string.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik: See my comment on the question, you need to make sure your element's `json` attribute is correctly output. I've also added a note about that to the end of the answer above.

Comment: Maybe I don't get something but your code returns that there are 12 cities so it consideres the values are strings, not array/lists.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik: Well-spotted. They **are** strings in the JSON. If you don't want them to be strings, remove the quotes around them.