# Finding value inside of a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hopefully I explain this correctly.

So what I have is a data-attribute which contains a lot of data, in this instance I want to find each individual basket product ID and spit them out as separate strings.

The main thing I am struggling with is how to actually find this amongst the other data that is present

Here is the markup I am working with:

```
<div class="hidden js-page-context" data-page-context="{
    &quot;basketProductIds&quot;: &quot;FZZ83047-157-16,FZZ84695-173-20&quot;,
    &quot;basketLastModified&quot;: &quot;Mon Aug 12 12:06:43 GMT 2019&quot;,
    &quot;redirectUrl&quot;: &quot;https://www.test.com&quot;
}"></div>
```

```
var test = $('.hidden').attr("data-page-context");

console.log(test);
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/JgxmBb

Any help would be awesome :D

Comment: *will return the string "123"* — No, it won't. And I can't see why you think it might, `123` doesn't appear anywhere in the HTML.

Comment: I think you're missing my original point, ignore that comment because this is just getting everything inside of the data attribute, my question is, can I target or find specific values in side of the data-attribute, so to find the basket product IDs and spit that out rather than everything inside of it.

Comment: "I think you're missing my original point" — It helps when you ask a clear question in the first place. So are you asking how to parse JSON?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: @NickElse, try using Ulysse BN's answer, it reduces a step

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert HTML data attribute to JSON in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787480/how-to-convert-html-data-attribute-to-json-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
var test = $('.hidden').attr("data-page-context"); // will return the JSON
let testObj = JSON.parse(test);
console.log(testObj.basketProductIds); // The id you need
```

Comment: I'll give this a go :)

Comment: Genius! It worked, I'll accept this one.

Comment: `$(".hidden").data("page-context")` will return the parsed data - no need to use JSON.parse

Comment: no need for `JSON.parse` as by using `jQuery`'s `data` method an object will be returned and ready to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`JQuery.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/#jQuery-data2) to target `data-*` html elements:

```js
const test = $('.hidden').data("page-context")

console.log(test)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden js-page-context" data-page-context="{
    &quot;basketProductIds&quot;: &quot;FZZ83047-157-16,FZZ84695-173-20&quot;,
    &quot;basketLastModified&quot;: &quot;Mon Aug 12 12:06:43 GMT 2019&quot;,
    &quot;redirectUrl&quot;: &quot;https://www.test.com&quot;
}"></div>
```

This will give you an *object*, and you can access it's attributes quite easily. For instance, `test.basketProductIds` will give the corresponding data.

Comment: They could … but that doesn't get them the `123` they seem to be looking for

Comment: What makes you think that the OP doesn't know how to extract data from an attribute? `.attr("WHOLE_ATTRIBUTE")` also would return the same right?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt — they are using `.attr("data-*")`, which will give an unparsed string.  My interpretation of the question was that they wanted to use the given data, as an object. And that is what `.data()` offers.
@Quentin — The question is quite unclear, maybe my answer should be a comment, let's see if they edit further.

Comment: @UlysseBN, Your interpretation was correct after all. So +1 for this since it reduces a step.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to resolve your problems it's first of all, transform your string you have with :

```
var test = $('.hidden').attr("data-page-context");
```

use JSON.parse(test), to transform it in adequate JSON.

**EDIT :** as mentioned in other anwsers and comments : You can skip this part by using :

```
var item= $('.hidden').data("page-context");
```

After to get all individual id:

```
  var ids = item.basketProductIds.split(",");
```

to get an array of ids.

Check my snippet below.

```js
var test = $('.hidden').attr("data-page-context"); 

var item = JSON.parse(test);
console.log(item); 

console.log("ids", item.basketProductIds);

var ids = item.basketProductIds.split(",");
console.log(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden js-page-context" data-page-context="{
    &quot;basketProductIds&quot;: &quot;FZZ83047-157-16,FZZ84695-173-20&quot;,
    &quot;basketLastModified&quot;: &quot;Mon Aug 12 12:06:43 GMT 2019&quot;,
    &quot;redirectUrl&quot;: &quot;https://www.test.com&quot;
}"></div>
```

Comment: You can avoid the `JSON.parse` step using JQuery's `.data`, see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57461286/6320039).

Comment: @UlysseBN You are right to mention it.

Comment: `$(".hidden").data("page-context")` will return the parsed data - no need to use JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant this?

`$(...).data("page-context")` will return the parsed data - no need to use JSON.parse

The code below will find all divs with class `js-page-context` and return a list of all basketProductIds found in any of them

```js
var list = $('.js-page-context').map(
  (_,div) => $(div).data("page-context").basketProductIds.split(",")
).get()

console.log(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden js-page-context" data-page-context="{
    &quot;basketProductIds&quot;: &quot;FZZ83047-157-16,FZZ84695-173-20&quot;,
    &quot;basketLastModified&quot;: &quot;Mon Aug 12 12:06:43 GMT 2019&quot;,
    &quot;redirectUrl&quot;: &quot;https://www.test.com&quot;
}"></div>
<div class="hidden js-page-context" data-page-context="{
    &quot;basketProductIds&quot;: &quot;FZZ83047-157-17,FZZ84695-173-21&quot;,
    &quot;basketLastModified&quot;: &quot;Mon Aug 12 12:06:43 GMT 2019&quot;,
    &quot;redirectUrl&quot;: &quot;https://www.test.com&quot;
}"></div>
```