# How to preserve value type when serializing form data to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, forms

I want to convert all form values to JSON so that I can send the JSON as body in my AJAX POST. I found this existing solution online:

```
function getFormData($form){
    var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
    var indexed_array = {};

    $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
        indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
    });

    return indexed_array;
}
```

Usage:

```
var $form = $("#form_data");
var data = getFormData($form);
```

However, this approach ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11339012/8571146)) converts all values to type string, it does not preserve numbers as integers. I could not come up with a way to preserve the type of the values. What is the best way to do this?

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    <div>
      <label>Number: </label>
      <input id="mynum" type="number" name="mynum"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input id="myname" type="text" name="myname"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because all `input` values are by default of type `string`. If you want to convert the type to `number` type you have to do that manually.

One way to do that by looping through the `JSON` and use a manual function to parse `string` value back to the `number` type.

To create a manual function: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/01/14/JavaScript-intTryParse-Equivalent

The following code shows even if the `input` type is `number`, the type is actually `string`:

```js
let type;
function checkFormData(){
  type = document.getElementById('mynum').value;
  console.log('The type of input#mynum is: ' +typeof type);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform" onsubmit=" return checkFormData()">
  <div>
    <label>Number: </label>
    <input id="mynum" type="number" name="mynum"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input id="myname" type="text" name="myname"/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: But for some inputs I have input type="number", does that not help at all in this case

Comment: Can you add some html markup in the question to have a look?

Comment: see added html in post

Comment: @b11, though the type of `input` is number, it is actually a `string`. Please have a look my updated answer to check that...thanks.

Comment: So I have to use a manual function on every field of the form? That creates n number of function calls if there are n number of fields. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, if you need multiple number of field's value back to the `number` type. This is actually a enhanced version of built-in `parseInt` we normally use. If you are sure about the input is `number` only, then you can use `parseInt` as well....thanks.