# Jquery submit form without redirect

Tags: jquery, http, post

I have a html form:

```
<form method="post" action="apiCalls.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="ghf823y932yd928u">
</form>
```

I want to submit this form (so the request get sent to the php script) but without redirecting the page. I tried a lot of things like $.post, $.ajax, form.submit prevent defaults, etc., but without resolving my problem.

Comment: Ajax request would be the correct approach. What does your ajax code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is an ajax request

1. Fetch all the values from your form and put them in a dictionary. See [Serialize form data to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)
2. Then use `jQuery.post` and send those values to `apiCalls.php`.

Something like

```
// getFormData is defined in the referenced SO post
data = getFormData($("form"))
$.post("apiCalls.php", data)
```

Comment: I did it like this: $.post('apiCalls.php', {token: 'h8934fh9834f'}); Thanks! One more question - why I can't see the request in Network tab in dev tools?

Comment: You should be able to see it. Try refreshing the page, the network tab has to be active (already open) when you first load the page.

Comment: Yeah, I know it must be active, I just had JS filter by default. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ajaxForm/ajaxSubmit functions from [Ajax Form Plugin](https://jquery-form.github.io/form/) or the [jQuery serialize function](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize).

**AjaxForm**:

```
$("#formID").ajaxForm({url: 'apiCalls.php', type: 'post'})
```

**Serialize**:

```
$.post('apiCalls.php', $('#formID').serialize())
```

Also have a look at following resources:

1. [AJAX serialization documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize).
2. [jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)