# How to put JSON string into objects instead of one long string

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

My JSON string looks like this:

```
{  
   "main_object":{  
      "id":"new",
      "formData":"language=nl_NL&getExerciseTitle=3213&question_takeAudio_exerciseWord%5B0%5D=3213&Syllablescounter%5B0%5D=3213S&Syllablescounter%5B1%5D=321"
   }
}
```

As you can see I have `language=nl_NL`, but I am looking to have it like this -> `"language": "nl_NL` and so on, instead of the `&` in between.

This is most likely what is causing the long string ->

```
function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {
    $("#my_form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'saveJson.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: getUrlParameter('id'),
                formData: $('#my_form').serialize()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(response) {

        });
    });
}
```

The part where it is being `serialize()`, but to be honest: I have no idea what to do to change this, I read something about `serializeArray()` but that will display it in my JSON file like this -> `"name": "exampleForStackOverflow": "value": "TheValueGiven"` something that looks like this.
So does anyone have a solution on how to change my AJAX so it won't end up being one long string? But for it to be like `"language": "nl_NL"` etc.?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11338832/4437464

Comment: I took a look and @STEEL had a good solution (it seems), but I am wondering: What does the .datahere means in his code? which data is he refering to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your urlParameter format to Object like this :

```js
var obj = {
  "id": "new",
  "formData": "language=nl_NL&getExerciseTitle=3213&question_takeAudio_exerciseWord%5B0%5D=3213&Syllablescounter%5B0%5D=3213S&Syllablescounter%5B1%5D=321"
};

obj.formData = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(obj.formData).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"') + '"}');

console.log(obj.formData);
```

In your code :

```
function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {
    $("#my_form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'saveJson.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: getUrlParameter('id'),
                formData: JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI($('#my_form').serialize()).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"') + '"}')
            },
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(response) {

        });
    });
}
```

## Other solution :

```
function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {
    $("#my_form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'saveJson.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#my_form').serialize() + "&id=" + getUrlParameter('id'),
        }).done(function(response) {

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: and where should I implement this piece of code if u don't mind me asking? and you have var obj = and then the direct string, but what if the var obj has to remain a variable (because the data is changing constantly with everything being inserted and sent)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, THANK YOU SO MUCH. ONE WEEK OF SUFFERING AND IT FINALLY WORKS. GOD BLESS YOUR HANDS.

Comment: @D.Sof Also, you can try : `data : $('#form').serialize() + "&id=" + getUrlParameter('id')`, it's maybe more efficient.

Comment: how is it more sufficient?

Comment: There is less operation