# How do I get the 2nd defined radio button value?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my html code.

```
<form id="item">
<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-sx-3">
     <label for="itemtype">Hotel</label>
     <input type="radio" class="radio" id="itemtype" name="optradio" value="H" checked>
     <label for="itemtype">AirPort</label>
     <input type="radio" class="radio" id="itemtype" name="optradio" value="A">
</div>
</form>
```

And this is my jquery.

```
function save() {
    debugger

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { "item": { "itemid": $("#itemid").val(),  "itemtype": $('#itemtype').val() }},
        url: "@Url.Action("Save", "Item")",
        cache:false,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            if (data.isSuccess) {
                alert("Saved Succesfully!");
                window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Item")";
            }
        }, error: function (err) {
            alert("Saved Failed!")
            debugger
        }
});
}
```

All the time when I trying to save the item type call "A", it never happen. Always this query getting radio button value as "H". I need to pass the 2nd value "A".

Comment: just change your second radio button id, and try to access using new id. you will always get first control value if you use same id for multiple controls.

Comment: Having the same id on two elements is not good practice, and if you want the "A" send as value it must have "checked" property.

Comment: Better still, remove the id attribute if you are not doing anything with it on client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the correct value by using the name, please remove the duplicate id

```
$('input[name=optradio]:checked', '#item').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=optradio]:checked').val();
```

it is not recommended to have two identical ids on one page

---

other solution using class name:

```
<form id="item">
<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-sx-3">
     <label for="itemtype">Hotel</label>
     <input type="radio" class="radio itemtype" name="optradio" value="H" checked>
     <label for="itemtype">AirPort</label>
     <input type="radio" class="radio "itemtype" name="optradio" value="A">
</div>
</form>
```

```
$('.itemtype:checked').val();
```

---

In jquery the best way to send data form a formular is to use [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) methods.

Some exemple : [serialize-form-data-to-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)