# how to Insert Multiple Username and Password into localStorage with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, local-storage

I try to save every values of the form that I made, username, lastname, email and password, my problem is, how can I push different names and other mentioned above keys to local storage? because the data is being rewrite everytime I save another. please be patient, beginner here, thank you!

```js
const firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
const lastnName = document.getElementById("lastName");
const email = document.getElementById("newEmail");
const password = document.getElementById("newPassword");

const btnSignup = document.getElementById("btn-signup");

btnSignup.onclick = function () { // when mouse click "signup" button
    const first_name = firstName.value; 
    const last_name = lastName.value;
    const e_mail = newEmail.value;
    const pass_word = newPassword.value;

    if (first_name && last_name && e_mail && pass_word) {
        localStorage.setItem("First Name", first_name);
        localStorage.setItem("Last Name", last_name);
        localStorage.setItem("Email", e_mail);
        localStorage.setItem("Password", pass_word);
    } else {
        alert("Please fill out the forms.");
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome!
Look at @firatozcevahir's answer.
I'm assuming you know how to get data from localStorage.
I would make an object `users` with two properties: `nextId` (say, integer, initially 0) and `users` (an object with keys `id` and the four you already have, or, a concatenation of first, last and email) - read that, add new user, save that (using `users=JSON.parse(localStorage.users)` to read, `localStorage.users=JSON.stringify(users)` to save).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost - never store password in local storage and never store in  plain text.

You should send it straight to the API, get the token and store it in cookies instead in localstorage.

To store multiple values in local storage you can use `JSON.stringify` to transform `object` into `string` and then store it as a value.

But as I can see you get value from every input separately. I assume that you wrapped whole form in `<form>` tag so you can just use attribute `onsubmit` to get whole form as an object just like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/11338832/6599826 and then remove all those `document.getElementById...` variables.

As you finish that you can just take whole form to JSON.stringify and pass it to localStorage.

```js
localStorage.setItem("UserFormData", JSON.stringify(form));
```

Then to retrieve this data you can use `localStorage.getItem` and parse it to object using `JSON.parse`.

```js
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UserFormData"));
```

Comment: Thank you Igor! I will ask again if something goes stuck again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can save your values like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("User1", JSON.stringify({
   firstName: first_name,
   lastName: last_name,
   eMail: email,
   password: pass_word
}));
```

And for another user you can use **User2** key:

```
localStorage.setItem("User2", JSON.stringify({
   firstName: first_name,
   lastName: last_name,
   eMail: email,
   password: pass_word
}));
```