# Convert FormData to json with grouped properties

Tags: javascript, json, form-data

I have a form, let's say:

```
<form action="bla">
    <div>
        <input name="form[row1][foo]"
        <input name="form[row1][bar]"
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="form[row2][foo]"
        <input name="form[row2][bar]"
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="form[row3][foo]"
        <input name="form[row3][bar]"
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to convert that FormData to json but when I do that

```
var formData = new FormData(myForm);
var jsonData = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
```

what I get is an object like:

```
{
    "form[row1][foo]": "foo1",
    "form[row1][bar]": "bar1",
    "form[row2][foo]": "foo2",
    "form[row2][bar]": "bar2",
    "form[row3][foo]": "foo3",
    "form[row3][bar]": "bar3"
}
```

but what I want is something like this:

```
{
    "form": {
        "row1": {
            "foo": "foo1",
            "bar": "bar1"
        },
        "row2": {
            "foo": "foo2",
            "bar": "bar2"
        },
        "row3": {
            "foo": "foo3",
            "bar": "bar3"
        }
    }
}
```

Is that possible and how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialize form data to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Are there any non-jQuery answers there?

Comment: @Barmar Hmmmm, no there don't seem to be. How frustrating.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, I'm indeed looking for a solution without jQuery.