# Using Foreach or another function to reduce the amount of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

please help. I have such a code with Checkboxes. I need to shorten it, namely to go through it through Foreach.
If you can shorten it in another way, then please write it..

```
let FormData = {
   DisplayName: $("#DisplayName").is(":checked"),
   Department: $("#Department").is(":checked"),
   Post: $("#Post").is(":checked"),
   Phone: $("#Phone").is(":checked"),
   Location: $("#Location").is(":checked"),
   Dinner: $("#Dinner").is(":checked")
} 
console.log(JSON.stringify(FormData));
```

I haven't really tried anything yet. But I didn't really find the answer I needed..

Comment: These appear to be what you're after:  [Serialize form to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json) / [Convert form to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery) - put your inputs in a `<form>` and do `Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form))` (non jquery version) there's lots of other options on those questions.

Comment: Sorry, but.. I need to iteratively shorten this code. Namely with the help of *Foreach*

Comment: So ... you want to make the code *longer* than it needs to be?

Comment: On the contrary, I need to shorten it. I've already found a great answer, which is below. Therefore, thank you for the help offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the names of the checkboxes and you want to perform this operation of collecting their state on all the checkboxes of a form, you can use this code.

```
var jsonObject = {};

// For each checkbox - Feed Json object
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index){ jsonObject[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).is(':checked'); });

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
```

The principle is to use a selection of the checkboxes present on the page to then perform a loop on this selection and recover for each of the boxes their ID and their state.

Comment: Hello, what you need. Thank you. But I will have one more request for you. If you can help me with that... Now I need to add a profileId or my own element to this JSON.

Comment: Generate the `jsonObject` (which will be a javascript object, add your additional fields *to the object* - *then* call `JSON.stringify(obj)` - don't try and "add to the JSON" - it's simply not worth the effort compared with a simple `obj.field = value`.

Comment: @AlexanderDegurechaff. I'm glad if this solution is what you need but I don't understand what you mean by "I need to add a profileid"

Comment: @Juan All good. I did everything on the sly myself. So don't worry. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the fields separately in an array and then use the `Array.reduce` method to make the object you want:

```js
let FormData = ['DisplayName', 'Department', 'Post', 'Phone', 'Location', 'Dinner'].reduce((acc, field) => {
    acc[field] = $(`#${field}`).is(':checked');
    return acc;
}, {});
```