# MVC extra hidden checkbox in forms breaking custom css checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am trying to customize the look and feel of the checkboxes in my ASP.NET MVC site, using a technique like the one detailed here:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles

They work great except when placed in a form.  When using the @Html.CheckBoxFor() method, MVC adds an extra hidden checkbox, apparently to make sure that a value is submitted to the form POST when the checkbox is not checked:  [asp.net mvc: why is Html.CheckBox generating an additional hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input)

When the extra hidden checkbox is on the form, my custom checkbox does not work.  I click it but it does not toggle between the states.  If I remove the extra hidden checkbox, then it works, but I guess I'll run into problems submitting the POST.

Here is the final html:

```
<div class="kbcheckbox">
    <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Approved field is required." id="UserEdit_IsApproved" name="UserEdit.IsApproved" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="UserEdit.IsApproved" type="hidden" value="false">
    <label for="UserEdit_IsApproved"></label></div>
</div>
```

And here is the css I am using (uses scss)

```
.kbcheckbox {
    width: $checkbox_size;  
    height: $checkbox_size;
    position: relative;

    input[type="checkbox"]{
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    label {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        width: $checkbox_size;
        height: $checkbox_size;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        border-radius: $control_corner_radius;
        border: 1px solid $control_border_color;
        /*@include box-shadow(1px, 1px, 1px, 0, $control_border_color, inset);*/ 
        /*@include box-shadow(0px, 1px, 0px, $control_background);*/
        background: white;
    }

    label:after {
        opacity: 0;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: $checkbox_size * 0.62;
        height: $checkbox_size * 0.25;
        background: transparent;
        top: $checkbox_size * 0.2;
        left: $checkbox_size * 0.1;
        border: 3px solid black;
        border-top: none;
        border-right: none;

        @include transform(rotate(-45deg));
    } 

    label:hover {
        background: darken($control_background, 10%);
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 I'm having a similar issue with a theme from WrapBootstrap.  The only idea I have had is to create a JS function to move the hidden input into a more appropriate location.  Did you ever manage to solve this issue another way?

Comment: I've just asked a similar question here.  I didn't see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368500/default-css3-checkbox-template-in-mvc

Answer (score 2):

Use the following in your css. You want all your elements to be modified.

```
input[type = checkbox]:checked ~ label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitsaxena17/emx7o1Lo/)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by wiring up an event when the checkbox is checked to change the value on an MVC hidden field instead, essentially doing the same thing without using the MVC helper

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserEdit.IsApproved, new { @id = "chkIsApproved" })
```

Here is your HTML then

```
<div class="kbcheckbox">
    <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Approved field is required." id="UserEdit_IsApproved" name="UserEdit.IsApproved" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <label for="UserEdit_IsApproved"></label></div>
</div>
```

Then just use some jQuery to wire up the checked property with the hidden field

```
$('#UserEdit_IsApproved').change(function() {
    $('#chkIsApproved').val($(this).is(':checked'));        
});
```

As long as the MVC hidden field is somewhere, the value will be posted to the controller. It is a little extra work, but it should get you the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is somewhat hacky but you can just move all hidden fields before the checkboxes using jQuery

```
 $(".checkbox > input[type=checkbox]").each(function( key, checkbox ) {
    var hidden = $(checkbox).siblings("input[type=hidden]");
    $(hidden).insertBefore($(checkbox));
 });
```