# How to get the boolean value of checkbox in ASP.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a checkbox in .cshtml page;

```
@Html.CheckBox("All", new { @class = "chkBox"})
```

I want to get the boolean value of this checkbox in my controller class, for that I have tried

```
bool all = Convert.ToBoolean(collection["All"]);
```

where `collection` is the object of `FormCollection` Class.
But I am getting value of the checkbox as "`all`", I don't know how to get the checked or unchecked value using formcollection object.

If anyone have any Idea then please tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys for all of your answers, all make sense. But in accordance of achieving the above requirement I have modified my .cshtml code a bit, rather then using razor syntax I am using this in my .cshtml page

```
<input id="All" name="All" value="true" type="checkbox" class="chkBox" />
```

Now in my .cs page I have harvested the boolean value as follows;

```
all = Convert.ToBoolean(collection["All"]);
```

So, basically what it does is, if the checkbox is left unchecked then it will give `value` as `false` otherwise, formcollection will take into account the checkbox and will give the value of `all` as `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not bind it to a model?

```
public class MyModel {
    public bool All {get; set;}
}
```

In your view just do the following

```
@html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.All)
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Get that In this way also:

Let us assume your controller name is Index

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(bool All)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

If "All"(Checkbox) is Checked then All becomes true.

If "All"(Checkbox) is UNchecked then All becomes false.

Based on true or false You can modify your code in your way.

Note:The variable you mentioned in Post Controller Must be same as the name which you given for checkbox in cshtml.

i.e;

@Html.CheckBox("**All**", new { @class = "chkBox" })

public ActionResult Index(bool **All**)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you input tag has the value as `all`. In this case, it's a good pratice to bind the right type, for sample:

```
public ActionResult Post(bool all)
{
   //here you will get the all boolean value, if check or not as boolean
}
```

Or, better than this, you could create a [ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_model) and bind it, for sample:

Add a class wih the fields you want to use on the Models folder.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public bool All { get; set; }
}
```

After it, in your View, you just type the View and create the controls using the Html helpers, for sample:

```
@model Models.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Post", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.All)

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

*Obs: it's just a sample*

And in your controller, you just get a instance of this model, and let asp.net mvc bind it for you as the object:

```
public ActionResult Post(MyViewModel model)
{
    // here you have the model.All as boolean value

}
```

It's a good pratice to do, because ViewModels represents the fields you need on the View and transfer it between contexts (controllers, views, services, apis, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach. You can get the more information from here [asp.net mvc: why is Html.CheckBox generating an additional hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input)

```
    bool all = (collections["all"] != "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code like this. Its working: you need to first convert it in string then convert to boolean.

```
 Convert.ToBoolean(collection["All"].ToString());
```