# Creating A Helper To Override CheckboxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using bootstrap 5 in a new project I am starting, and rather than having to write all the scaffolding around a form field, I have decided to create a wrapper to do this for me automatically.

I have used the following syntax for textboxfor, textareafor and dropdownlist:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var stringbuilder = new MvcHtmlString("<div class='form-group'>" +
                                                    helper.LabelFor(expression, new {@class = "col-sm-3 control-label"}) +
                                                    "<div class='col-sm-5'>" +
                                                        helper.TextBoxFor(expression, new {@class = "form-control"}) +
                                                    "</div>" +
                                              "</div>");

        return stringbuilder;
    }
```

Which can then be called as follows:

`@FormHelpers.MyTextBoxFor(Html, x => x.Name)`

However this does not appear to work for checkboxfor:

`Error  1   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>' does not contain a definition for 'CheckBoxFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.CheckBoxFor<TModel>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments`

If I change `TProperty` to `bool` it will then compile, but I get a runtime error on the line where I call this helper:

`CS0411: The type arguments for method 'CollectionSystem.Helpers.FormHelpers.MyCheckboxFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,bool>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Can someone advise how I can go about wrapping the CheckboxFor function please.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56256649/5836671

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You helper would need to be like

```
public static MvcHtmlString BootstrapCheckBoxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression)
{

  TagBuilder innerContainer = new TagBuilder("div");
  innerContainer.AddCssClass("col-sm-5");
  innerContainer.InnerHtml = helper.CheckBoxFor(expression, new {@class = "form-control"}).ToString();

  StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
  html.Append(helper.LabelFor(expression, new {@class = "col-sm-3 control-label"}));
  html.Append(innerContainer.ToString());

  TagBuilder outerContainer = new TagBuilder("div");
  outerContainer.AddCssClass("form-group");
  outerContainer.InnerHtml = html.ToString();

  return MvcHtmlString.Create(outerContainer.ToString());

}
```

Note you may want to edit this to include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`

Answer (score 10):

Stop and remove all this code from your project immediately.

What you want are editor templates. First, create a new folder at `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates`. Then, in that folder, create views named after either a type or one of the members of the `DataType` enum. For example:

**Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\String.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-control">
    @Html.Label("", new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue.ToString(), new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Or for your checkbox scenario, for example:

**Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Boolean.cshtml**

```
@model Boolean?
<div class="form-control">
    <div class="col-offset-sm-3 col-sm-5">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                @Html.CheckBox("", Model ?? false)
                @ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName() 
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Rinse and repeat with anything else you need. Then in your views, you just need to do:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TheProperty)
```

And based on the type of the property or what `DataType` it's decorated with, the right editor template will be used, and no custom helpers that developers have to remember to use.

I have a more in depth explanation on my blog here:

- [Display Templates and Editor Templates for Fun and Profit](http://cpratt.co/displaytemplates-and-editortemplates-for-fun-and-profit/)
- [Html.EditorFor and htmlAttributes](http://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes/)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am just reading your blog. I found typo in thesection: "Sounds simple enough. What's the catch?", first paragraph, third line, "...a model for thse views..."

Comment: @Chris Pratt what about using both Checkboxes and Radiobuttons with EditorTemplates ?

Comment: Radios aren't typically utilized for a `bool` type, unless you literally want a radio for both the true and false values. Still, if you want to be able to handle the same type, `bool` in this case, with either one, you'll need some way to differentiate. That could be done a number of ways. You can use something like `[UIHint("Radio")]` on your property to specify that a `Radio.cshtml` editor template should be used. Or you could pass some value into the templates `ViewData` and branch on that: `Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeBool, new { useRadios = true })`, then branch on `ViewData["useRadios"]`