# Custom strongly-typed HTml helper does not return property value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am trying to learn how to make strongly-typed Html helpers. I tried a few websites and I found the Code Project's website [Custom Strongly-typed HtmlHelpers in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/389747/Custom-Strongly-typed-HtmlHelpers-in-ASP-NET-MVC), and the Ode to Code's website, [Why All The Lambdas?](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/11/26/why-all-the-lambdas.aspx) very useful.

I pretty much copy pasted a code from Code Project and changed it slightly. I tried to make a custom html helper that will follow Bootstrap styles: `BootstrapTextBoxFor()`--the code below. It is supposed to render a text box with its label. For some reasons `Metadata.Model` is null and I cannot get property name. What I mean is I have expected to get a value specified in `[Display]` attribute. For instance

```
[Display("User Name")]
public string username { get; set; }
```

The code

```
public static MvcHtmlString BootstrapTextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string value, string type = "text", int labelCol = 2, int editorCol = 6)
{
    StringBuilder tags = new StringBuilder(); //.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    tags.AppendLine(@"<div class=""form-group"">");
    tags.AppendFormat(@"<label class=""col-md-{0}"" for=""{1}"">{2}</label>", labelCol, name, value).Append(Environment.NewLine);
    tags.AppendFormat(@"<div class=""col-md-{0}"">", editorCol).Append(Environment.NewLine);
    tags.AppendLine(@"<div class=""input-group"">");
    tags.AppendFormat(@"<input type=""{0}"" class=""form-control"" id=""{1}"" />", type, name);
    tags.AppendLine(@"</div>");
    tags.AppendLine(@"</div>");
    tags.AppendLine(@"</div>");

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tags.ToString());
}

public static MvcHtmlString BootstrapTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    return BootstrapTextBox(htmlHelper, name, metadata.Model as string);
}
```

Comment: Your not creating a valid helper that's suitable for use by MVC (its ignores model binding and validation!). You need to use the htmlHelper methos to render the label and input [Refer example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303529/creating-a-helper-to-override-checkboxfor/27304443#27304443)

Comment: And the `[Display]` attribute is the used by `LabelFor()` which you don't even use.