# CSS selector for 'next but one' element, checkboxes & labels in MVC forms

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am using [this](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953) reference to create some styled checkboxes. It refers to using the `+` selector to get the label following the checkbox:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {}
```

When the `html` is:

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<label>Label</label>
```

However, I am using MVC and Razor. When I use the following helpers:

```
@Html.CheckBox(...)
@Html.Label(...)
```

The following `html` is produced (as detailed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input)):

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="hidden" />
<label></label>
```

An additional hidden input is produced between the checkbox and the input. This prevents the `+` selector in the `CSS` from finding the `label` as it is no longer the next element to the `checkbox`. How can I select the `label` in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + input[type="hidden"] + label {}
```

Or if you want to target any element following after checkbox is then you may use the following:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + * + label {}
```

Comment: not all labels? OP wants to select all labels there after?