# Why I've got Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown. in my own htmlhelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I've written htmlhelper for checkbox in asp.net mvc but when I want to use it.It shows me a exception.`System.StackOverflowException' was thrown`How to solve it.and I also how to submit checkbox value to htmlhelper in fact,I want to submit value checkbox to my htmlhelper.

```
 public static class HelperUI
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxSimple(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool IsCheck, string name, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            string checkBoxWithHidden = htmlHelper.CheckBoxSimple(IsCheck, name, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString();
            string pureCheckBox = checkBoxWithHidden.Substring(0, checkBoxWithHidden.IndexOf("<input", 1));
            return new MvcHtmlString(pureCheckBox);
        }
    }




<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group row">
        status
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.CheckBoxSimple(true, "Status", new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "status" })

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first line of `CheckBoxSimple` is... calling itself. What did you *expect* that line of code to do?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever,my goal is remove hidden value in checkbox.[why is Html.CheckBox generating an additional hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input)

Comment: The debugger would have told you this pretty fast.

Comment: So, did you perhaps intend to write `htmlHelper.CheckBox(...` rather than `htmlHelper.CheckBoxSimple(...`?

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24341662/15498) to the question you linked to. It's *similar* to your code, except the first line of that method calls the `CheckBox` method. **your** version is calling `CheckBoxSimple`, which is *your* method - so as I said in my first comment, you're just calling your own method over and over again until the stack is used up.

Comment: *i love the smell of recursion in the morning*

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever,OMG,I didn't see it.

Comment: You need a base case which will exit from your recursive calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StackOverflowException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx)s are often caused by an infinite loop or infinite recursion.

In your case `CheckBoxSimple` is calling itself indefinitely : the first line calls `CheckBoxSimple` instead of `CheckBox`.