# ASP.NET Core 2 MVC CheckBoxFor always returning false in model

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, checkboxfor

I know there were a number of people that faced this issue but I don't feel like they ever resolved it.

I have a razor page like this:

```
@model MyModel
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("MyMethod", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MyBool)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyBool)
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Fire it up" />
    }
</div>
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DisplayName("My checkbox")]
    public bool MyBool {get; set;}
}
```

And my method in the home controller looks like this:

```
public IActionResult MyMethod(MyModel model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Everything looks good to me, but then, no matter if I check the checkbox or not, the model parameter in the MyMethod method is always false after I submit the form.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

When I check the checkbox the GET request contains both values - true and false.
I saw some people say that MVC should handle it but it apparently doesn't.

Comment: Did your form's GET request send something like this: `MyBool=true&MyBool=false`? This is related to how `CheckBoxFor` helper generates HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input. Check `model.MyBool` inside `MyMethod` to confirm this behavior.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Yes, the GET request looks exactly like that. The model.MyBool value inside MyMethod is always false, regardless the checkbox state.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7bzeDm) and found that the request URL query string looks exactly like mentioned before, but `MyBool` property was properly set to `true`. Can you provide Core MVC version to make sure?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto .NET Core 2.1

Comment: I followed these steps using a test project in my own machine: check the checkbox, submit the form, get request query string (`/Home/MyMethod?MyBool=true&MyBool=false`) and returns same view, the checkbox is still on checked state, not unchecked as stated in your question. The debugger also mentioned `MyBool` set as `true` after submit.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what happens is that when you don't check an HTML checkbox, the value sent by default is **null**.
But when you are using the HTML helper **@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MyBool)**, it is automatically creating a Checkbox for the MyBool value as you asked, and additionally a
**@Html.Hidden("MyBool",false)**. What this will do is, if MyBool doesn't have any value (if checkbox isn't checked), it will pass False, instead of null.

HTML created:

```
  <input id="MyBool" name="MyBool" type="checkbox" value="true">
  <input name="MyBool" type="hidden" value="false">
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. The answer doesn't really tell me anything. Both checked and unchecked return false.