# Dynamic checkbox is not showing selected value in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, checkbox, razor-pages

I have a checkbox list where the values are loaded from a database table. When the user selects particular customer, it is updating the database value to '1', but in the razor pages view the values are showing unchecked. I am not sure where i am going wrong.

This is my code:

`AccessRights` (model class)

```
public class AccessRights
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Users")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string ADUsername { get; set; }        
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedTimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

`Edit.cshtml`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label  class="control-label"> Access To Customers</label>
    <div class="checkbox checkboxlist">
    @{
        foreach (var customers in Model.CustomersChecked)
        {
            <input type="checkbox" id="@customers.Value" value="@customers.Value" name="CustomersChecked" checked="@customers.Selected" />
            <label class="text-black">@customers.Text</label><br/>
            //<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.CustomersChecked" value="@customers.Id">
        }
    }
    </div>
    <span class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

`Edit.cshtml.cs`:

```
[BindProperty]
public List<SelectListItem> CustomersChecked { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
    if (id == null || _context.AccessRights == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var accessrights = await _context.AccessRights.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeId == id);
    AccessRights = accessrights;

    CustomersChecked = (from p in _context.AccessRights.Where(m => m.EmployeeId == id)
                        select new SelectListItem
                               {
                                   Text = p.CustomerName,
                                   Value = p.CustomerId.ToString()
                               }).ToList();
    
    return Page();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string[] CustomersChecked)
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = (from p in _context.AccessRights.Where(m => m.EmployeeId == AccessRights.EmployeeId)
                                  select new SelectListItem
                                         {
                                              Text = p.CustomerName,
                                              Value = p.CustomerId.ToString()
                                         }).ToList();

    foreach (SelectListItem item in items)
    {
        if (CustomersChecked.Contains(item.Value))
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            item.Selected = false;
        }

        AccessRights.LastModifiedBy = HttpContext.Session.GetString("DisplayName").Trim();
        AccessRights.LastModifiedTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;

        await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"UPDATE [AccessRights] SET [isSelected] = {item.Selected}, [LastModifiedBy] = {AccessRights.LastModifiedBy}, [LastModifiedTimeStamp] = {AccessRights.LastModifiedTimeStamp} WHERE [EmployeeId] = {AccessRights.EmployeeId} AND [CustomerName] = {item.Text}");
    }

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not setting the `SelectListItem.Selected` flag when you load the page

Comment: it's usually easier to use the htmlhelper: @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model.CustomersChecked[i].Selected)  Use a for loop to get the "i".   @for (var i = 0; i < Model.CustomersChecked.Count(); i++)
            { ... otherwise you have to if/then in the markup based on the Selected bool.  One with "checked" attribute, and one without.  It also makes for easier binding when posted.  (Just bind to same class object used in the page instead of using a <SelectList>, which is for pulldowns.)

Comment: Hi @Mateus Zampol, how can i set SelectListItem.Selected on page load. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Hi @pcalkins, Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this, but it is not working and i have other fields also, which is not using HtmlHelper. So if i change this field with HtmlHelper i had to change other fields also. Is there anyother way it can be done without changing to HtmlHelper?

Answer (score 0):

Without using an HTMLHelper, you'd do something like this:

```
foreach (var customers in Model.CustomersChecked)
   {
     @if (customers.Selected)
     {
 <input type="checkbox" id="@customers.Value" value="@customers.Value" name="CustomersChecked" checked />        
     }
     else
     {
<input type="checkbox" id="@customers.Value" value="@customers.Value" name="CustomersChecked" />
     }
   }
```

Reading the state, though, can get complicated.  I believe you will only get checked values back to the controller unless you use some hidden fields with the same name attribute and values of each set to true or false.  Two falses = unchecked, true & false = checked.  See the answer here if you come up against this: [ASP.NET CORE Checkbox how to check for true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803453/asp-net-core-checkbox-how-to-check-for-true)  The HTMLHelper will automatically add the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a checkbox list where the values are loaded from a database
> table. When the user selects particular customer, it is updating the
> database value to '1', but in the razor pages view the values are
> showing unchecked. I am not sure where i am going wrong.

If you would like to keep your checkbox selected all you need to do is, loop through the selectedList items and find the value which has been selected and set it to `true`.

According to your code, its seems alright up to foreach loop where you are rebinding the value.

However, while redirecting to index, not sure how you are binding the updated value. With the updated value you should better use a for loop in view in order to display the selected checkbox.

> Is there anyother way it can be done without changing to HtmlHelper?

Yes, it can be done, you should use the loop, preferably forloop and the value you have save earlier need to provide to the forloop to your desired view.

Let's have a look in practice,

Assuming we have following Model:

```
public class AccessRights
{
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? ModuleName { get; set; }
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }
    
}
```

I am taking Additional ViewModel:

```
public class AccessRightsViewModel
 {
     public List<AccessRights>? AccessRights { get; set; }
 }
```

When you post selected value:

```
   public IActionResult UpatedCheckBoxView(List<string> selectedValues)
    {
        var accessVirtualList = new List<AccessRights>()
        {
            new AccessRights() { Id=1,ModuleName="Module-UserAccess", isSelected = false },
            new AccessRights() { Id=2,ModuleName="Module-Sales", isSelected = false },
            new AccessRights() { Id=3,ModuleName="Module-Dev", isSelected = false },
            new AccessRights() { Id=4,ModuleName="Module-Test", isSelected = false },



        };


        // Set IsChecked to true for selected values
        if (selectedValues != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in accessVirtualList)
            {
                item.isSelected = selectedValues.Contains(item.Id.ToString());
            }
        }

        var model = new AccessRightsViewModel
        {
            AccessRights = accessVirtualList
        };

        return View("UpatedCheckBoxView", model);
    }
}
```

View: to keep the value selected:

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Controllers.AccessRightsViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Selected Check Box List";
}
<h4>Selected Module checkbox</h4>
<form asp-action="SubmitCombatantSelectedValue" asp-controller="CheckboxSelectedValue" method="post">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered mr-3 ml-3">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Select?</th>

        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AccessRights?.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>

                <td> @Model.AccessRights[i].ModuleName</td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.AccessRights[i].isSelected" /></td>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AccessRights[i].Id" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AccessRights[i].ModuleName" />

            </tr>

        }

    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit To Controller</button>
</form>
```

Output:

[image]