# Why does the value of my checkbox not post to my controller when it's set by jQuery in my ASP.NET Core Web Application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I am using the KendoUI for ASP.NET Core in my web application.  I have a custom editor for a particular column that is used when someone edits data in the grid.  The grid is set to `auto-sync="true"` so that the user can edit data in the cells and the changes are committed automatically.

Within the custom editor is a checkbox that I set with jQuery based on certain conditions.  Even though this function works and the checkbox becomes "checked" the value the controller receives is always `false`.

Here is my grid.

***/Views/Home/Index***

```
<kendo-grid name="HomePositionGrid" deferred="false">
    <datasource type="DataSourceTagHelperType.Ajax" auto-sync="true">
        <transport>
            <read url="/Position/ReadPositions" />
            <update url="/Position/UpdatePosition" />
        </transport>
        <schema>
            <model id="Id">
                <fields>
                    <field name="Id" editable="false" />
                    </fields>
                </model>
            </schema>
        </datasource>
        <editable mode="incell" />           
        <columns>
            <column field="Name" title="Name" />
            <column field="ExpectedOffhire" editor="expectedOffhireEditor" title="ExpectedOffhire" />               
        </columns>
    </kendo-grid>
```

As you can see it's a tag helper grid with `auto-sync` set to `true` and a custom editor of `expectedOffhireEditor` defined.

Here is that editor

***wwwroot/js/expectedOffhireEditor***

```
function expectedOffhireEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input name="' + options.field + '" id="' + options.field + '" />')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDateTimePicker({
            valuePrimitive: true
        });

    $('<input name="PPT" id="PPT" />')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataValueField: "value",
            optionLabel: "-- Select --",
            change: setPromptDate,
            dataSource: [
                {
                    value: 1,
                    text: "Prompt"
                },
                {
                    value: 2,
                    text: "Prompt AM"
                },
                {
                    value: 3,
                    text: "Prompt PM"
                }
            ]            
        });  
    $('<input type="checkbox" id="Prompt" name="Prompt" for="Prompt" />').appendTo(container)
}
```

There are three inputs created here, the first is a DateTime picker, the second is a dropdown list and the third is a basic checkbox.  When the user selects an option from the dropdown list, it must set the checkbox to `checked` which is handled by the change event called `setPromptDate`.

***setPromptDate***

```
function setPromptDate(e) {           
    $('#Prompt').prop("checked", true);            

    //shortened for brevity ...
}
```

When the data is posted from the grid and reaches the controller, the value of the checkbox is always `false` I've tried various ways of doing it but `prompt` checkbox is just not posting.  If I check the box myself using the mouse, the value will post as"true", it's something to do with setting the checked status with jquery that isn't playing well.

Has anyone encountered this before who can shed some light on what is wrong?

Comment: You have given same `id` for all your checkboxes ?

Answer (score 2):

As you have stated "If I check the box myself using the mouse, the value will post as `true`". I'm guessing `setPromptDate` isn't working as intended. More specifically, `$('#Prompt').prop("checked", true)` isn't changing the `input type='checkbox'` HTML markup properly. I would try the following:

1. `$('#Prompt').checked`
2. `$('#Prompt').prop('checked')`
3. `$('#Prompt').attr('checked')`
4. `$('#Prompt').attr('checked', 'true')`

Or some other ways just to get to `<input type="checkbox" checked>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, try this:

```
change: function(options){ return setPromptDate(options); },
```

The function:

```
function setPromptDate(options) {           
    $('#Prompt').attr('checked', 'true');
    // The rest of process...
}
```

You can ignore the parameter "options" if you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

The `value` of a checkbox after posting is not `true` or `false`, it's whatever you set the `value=""` attribute to if it's checked; or it's unset if it's not checked.

I see you didn't set the value of the checkbox, and I'm guessing it's being set to `""`, which is falsey, or just `false` by default? It's worth a test.

---

Try the above first, but, if that doesn't work for you, try this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63418577/1410567

Copied here:

```
$('form').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).val(true);
    }
    else {
        $(this).val(false);
    }
});
```