# Binding Model not returning as expected

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, model-binding

Project is an ASP.NET Core 6 webapp. I have a property that has decorated with `[BindProperty]` with some object arrays inside of it. I have a page that has a form that displays all the properties of the model including the properties of the nested objects in the arrays. I have some js functions that add and remove form controls that correspond to the properties of my model bound object for the purposes of changing the amount of objects in the arrays. For example, I have a `Sources` array and the client decides to add a device, they push a plus button and boom new device object appears on the page. If I then post this object back to the `PageModel` the model bound property now has this new object in the device array with all the fields and comes up valid. HOWEVER, this does not work in the opposite. If the client wants to remove a device, the java-script function removes the HTML element but when it's posted, the `ModelState.MyProperty.Sources` still shows the device there in the array with all of it's properties as null.

It seems like whatever the model looks like going to the client, it comes back the same way? I see the `ModelState` dictionary that is generated still has entries for `Config.Sources[<deletedindex>].Id` when the HTML coming back to the server doesn't have any attributes that call for it.

As a note, `HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys` does NOT have entries for the removed array objects but `Model.Config.Sources` does.

JS functions in case these are my problem.

````
    const sourceSection = document.querySelector(".source-section");
    const nextCard = document.querySelectorAll(".source-card").length;
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.classList.add("col-6");
    newDiv.classList.add("p-4");
    newDiv.classList.add("border");
    newDiv.classList.add("source-card");

    newDiv.innerHTML = ` 
                        <div class="row col">
                            <h3>Source ${nextCard}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Id" class="col-6 my-1">Id</label>
                            <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="Source Id field can not be empty" id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Id" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Id" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Name" class="col-6 my-1">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Name" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Name" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        <div data-lastpass-icon-root="true" style="position: relative !important; height: 0px !important; width: 0px !important; float: left !important;"></div></div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Icon" class="col-6 my-1">Icon</label>
                            <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Icon field is required." id="Config_Sources_0__Icon" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Icon" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Icon" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Position" class="col-6 my-1">Position</label>
                            <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Position field is required." id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Position" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Position" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Position" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Label" class="col-6 my-1">Label</label>
                            <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Label field is required." id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Label" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Label" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Label" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__nsMessage" class="col-6 my-1">No Signal Message</label>
                            <input type="text" id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__nsMessage" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].nsMessage" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].nsMessage" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__nsHelpMessage" class="col-6 my-1">No Signal Help Message</label>
                            <input type="text" id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__nsHelpMessage" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].nsHelpMessage" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].nsHelpMessage" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__pMessage" class="col-6 my-1">Presentation Message</label>
                            <input type="text" id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__pMessage" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].pMessage" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].pMessage" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__pIcon" class="col-6 my-1">Presentation Icon</label>
                            <input type="text" id="Config_Sources_0__pIcon" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].pIcon" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].pIcon" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__nsIcon" class="col-6 my-1">No Signal Icon</label>
                            <input type="text" id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__nsIcon" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].nsIcon" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].nsIcon" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__subpageId" class="col-6 my-1">Subpage Id</label>
                            <input type="text" id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__subpageId" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].subpageId" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].subpageId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__HasVideo" class="col-6 my-1">Has Video</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Has Video field is required." id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__HasVideo" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].HasVideo" value="false" class="col-6 my-1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__HasAudio" class="col-6 my-1">Has Audio</label>
                            <input type="checkbox"  data-val="true" data-val-required="The Has Audio field is required." id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__HasAudio" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].HasAudio" value="false" class="col-6 my-1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__VideoRequired" class="col-6 my-1">Video Req.</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Video Req. field is required." id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__VideoRequired" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].VideoRequired" value="false" class="col-6 my-1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_0__BypassP" class="col-6 my-1">Bypass Presentation</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Bypass Presentation field is required." id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__BypassP" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].BypassP" value="false" class="col-6 my-1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_0__Disabled" class="col-6 my-1">Disabled</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Disabled field is required." id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Disabled" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Disabled" value="false" class="col-6 my-1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Pinned" class="col-6 my-1">Pinned</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Pinned field is required." id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Pinned" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Pinned" value="false" class="col-6 my-1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__DefaultMode" class="col-6 my-1">Default Mode</label>
                            <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Default Mode field is required." id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__DefaultMode" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].DefaultMode" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[0].DefaultMode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row seperator">
                            <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__DetectionId" class="col-6 my-1">Detection Id</label>
                            <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Detection Id field is required." id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__DetectionId" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].DetectionId" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].DetectionId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                            <h4>Route 0</h4>
                            <div class="row seperator">
                                <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Routes_0__Id" class="col-6 my-1">Id</label>
                                <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Routes_0__Id" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Routes[0].Id" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row seperator">
                                <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Routes_0__Input" class="col-6 my-1">Input</label>
                                <input type="text" id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Routes_0__Input" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Routes[0].Input" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row seperator">
                                <label for="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Routes_0__Output" class="col-6 my-1">Output</label>
                                <input type="text" id="Config_Sources_${nextCard}__Routes_0__Output" name="Config.Sources[${nextCard}].Routes[0].Output" value="" class="col-6 my-1">
                            </div>
                    `;

    sourceSection.appendChild(newDiv);
};

function removeSource() {
    const sourceSection = document.querySelector(".source-section");
    const sourceCards = document.querySelectorAll(".source-card");
    const target = sourceCards[sourceCards.length - 1];
    sourceSection.removeChild(target);
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. ASP.NET Core for every checkbox creates a hidden input field to keep track of the value. I don't know why this is the default behavior but it is. So when i removed the HTML element with javascript, it didn't remove the hidden input field which is located near the bottom of the body, so when the data posted back, the HTML still had `for=""` fields that called out for `Config.Sources[<deletedindex>]` which caused the model binder to create unwanted objects. You can stop ASP.NET from generating these hidden fields but adding

```
builder.Services.Configure<MvcViewOptions>(options =>
{
    // Disable hidden checkboxes
    options.HtmlHelperOptions.CheckBoxHiddenInputRenderMode = CheckBoxHiddenInputRenderMode.None;
});
```

to your `Program.cs` file. You can read more about that here [asp.net mvc: why is Html.CheckBox generating an additional hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input)